# Perguntas e respostas de baixa qualidade ocorrendo juntas

Tags: debate, perguntas, pergunta-específica

Ter péssimas perguntas e péssimas respostas vindas de usuários novos é normal. Entretanto, hoje aconteceu um evento um tanto curioso: Diversos usuários novos fazendo perguntas e respostas de péssima qualidade sobre um mesmo assunto em um curto espaço de tempo.

Eis as perguntas e respostas em questão:

- [O que é encapsulamento em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311433/132) - [resposta 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311435/132), [resposta 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311448/132)
- [em programação orientada a objeto, quantas interfaces posso vincular? e quantas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311449/132)
- [A respeito de POO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311460/132)
- [Programação Estruturada é melhor que programação Orientada a Objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311436/132) - [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311459/132)
- [Para que utilizamos a herança em programação orientada a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311454/132) - [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311458/132)
- [O que é dao em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311445/132) - [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311447/132)
- [Resposta em uma pergunta antiga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311451/132) - [outra resposta na mesma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311393/132)

Isso poderia ser alguma tentativa de sockpupetting ou algum esquema para fraudar votações?

Comment: Eu sinalizei as contas para a moderação.

Comment: Com certeza tem algo esquisito, estamos analisando, não é tão simples quanto parece.

Comment: @Maniero Pensei se não pode ser alguma coisa mais boba do tipo alguns colegas de faculdade que tem que fazer algum trabalho sobre POO e o professor recomendou a eles trazerem as perguntarem ao SOpt ou algo assim.

Comment: Pode ser, amos tratar isso com cuidado porque não d´á para afirmar má fé.

Comment: Me parecem perguntas de provas, lista de exercícios, etc.. coincide com o final de semestre, recuperação....

Comment: Se já existe uma pergunta como essa, seria bom marcar como duplicada e fechar, caso não exista e tenha muitas respostas de má qualidade, seria bom responder com uma de excelente qualidade, pois das perguntas usadas no exemplo muitas delas são dúvidas triviais da maioria das pessoas que começam a aprender a programar. Se o problema é na forma como a pergunta foi formulada seria bom orientar quem fez a perguntar a melhorar e editar a pergunta.