# Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos

Tags: debate, comunidade, qualidade

Temos notado uma baixa qualidade de perguntas de usuários tipicamente com 1 ponto ou pouco mais (acabaram de entrar ou estão fazendo uma das primeiras perguntas).

Não é novidade, mas está em nível alarmante. A imensa maioria é assim.

Principais problemas:

- título não diz nada (e o corpo não ajuda identificar)
- título e até corpo tudo em maiúsculo
- qualquer *tag* só pra "cumprir tabela"
- texto escrito sem nenhum critério, sem cuidado algum
- código externo, em imagem, ou colocado sem que possa ser analisado adequadamente
- não é um MCVE nem de perto
- muitos casos é um enunciado de exercício largado ou um "como faz tal coisa" sem nenhum esforço
- não explica nada de forma que dê para fazer alguma coisa sem muita conversa
- a pessoa não tem conhecimentos mínimos de programação ou mesmo de outras coisas para ajudar de forma efetiva, mesmo respondendo não estamos ajudando nem a ela, muito menos outras pessoas
- a pergunta já existe em diversas instâncias no site (cada vez mais comum os experientes também não acharem, ou nem procurarem, seja lá por qual motivo)

Agrava o fato de que pessoas votam positivo em perguntas neste estado, novatos, ou nem tanto que tentam dar um resposta que não faz o menor o sentido e aumenta a dificuldade.

Percebo uma certa letargia de muitos usuários que já cansaram de arrumar tantos problemas, de ficar tentando enxugar gelo, sem resultado. Não temos o volume do SO, muitos usuários ativos desistiram do site por completo ou estão fazendo apenas coisas pontuais, até os moderadores estão cansados (não posso falar pelos outros, mas acho que é perceptível) e a impressão que tenho que as pessoas que ainda gostariam de ser moderadores também ou já não estão mais tão ativos no site, ou não possuem confiança da comunidade (critério meu, posso estar enganado). Tem moderador que sequer usa o site, e tem moderador que talvez só use porque é moderador. E ando com vontade de acionar esse modo por não ver saída, daí estou pedindo ajuda de vocês. Nenhuma intenção de criticar a situação, estou mostrando algo que me parece óbvio e sinto que é legítimo que isto ocorra.

Sim, algumas coisas podem ser resolvidas editando, trocando vários comentários até que a pessoa consiga deixar em boas condições, mas é fato que muitas vezes isto não ocorre, há respostas "alopradas" que piora a situação, e acaba colocando um peso muito grande na comunidade para lidar com tanta coisa, tornando o SOpt algo igual ou pior que um fórum normal da internet desvirtuando, sob o meu ponto de vista, totalmente do objetivo do site, de fazer uma internet melhor, de conteúdo de qualidade, sem ruídos, que sirvam para outras pessoas.

Usuários mais ou menos novatos (alguns com anos) não sabem como ajudar, qual o objetivo do site, e muitas vezes aumentam o problema.

Tentativas de ajuda costumam dar tempo para acontecer mais problemas.

Em geral as perguntas são tratadas de qualquer jeito, de estado ruim, ou até lamentável, muitas vezes com voto positivo, e ficam ali pra sempre.

Fechamentos podem ajudar, mas costumam chegar tarde demais, e não têm ajudado muito. É comum o usuário não aparecer por horas, dias ou nunca mais. Eles não leem as dicas do bloco amarelinho do fechamento e muitas vezem nem quando algum usuário comenta. Eles só querem que alguém dê a solução e não demonstram esforço algum, nem antes e nem depois. Não é comum ficarem bravos quando alguém fecha a pergunta ou comenta mostrando o problema.

Não tem muito mais que uma dúzia de pessoas que participam do meta, mesmo quando tem destaque, muitos já experientes não sabem que ele existe. Mesmo quando tem seu uso, geralmente é por assuntos já tratados, repetitivos, muita discussão em cima de algo individual, muito trabalho para pouca coisa.

Votos positivos têm sido cada vez menos aplicados em conteúdo de qualidade. É provável que a quantidade seja maior, mas pulverizada. O problema aqui é destacar menos o que tem de qualidade. Mas também há poucas perguntas que mereçam destaque.

Tudo isso foi "cantado" no passado e aconteceu. O nível de ruído é bem maior que o de conteúdo útil. Disseram na época para se preocupar com problemas que estavam acontecendo, não com o que poderia acontecer. Pois bem, agora está acontecendo. E piorando quase a cada dia. Não estamos aumentando o número de perguntas diárias e a maioria não agregam valor ao site, a não ser pela quantidade.

Já há uma quantidade enorme de conteúdo que dá o tom de quem a baixa qualidade é aceitável.

Diversas tentativas já foram feitas para melhorar e nada. Tem o agravante de que o conteúdo ruim vem principalmente de usuário que não voltam mais. Dá para discutir se não voltam por falta de comprometimento mesmo, e muitos só pode ser por isso porque foram tratados bem demais, ou porque não receberam o tratamento dentro de suas expectativas, que não é o mesmo de serem mal tratados, algo que devemos evitar, mas é compreensível que ocorra, dado o volume de problemas, e o fato que tem usuários que também não entendem o funcionamento do site.

É de se temer que venha aí um código de conduta quando até coisas universalmente conhecidas que fazem parte da etiqueta na internet, ou até dentro da ética, ainda que hoje em dias esses conceitos andam mais nebulosos do que deveriam.

Não ajuda o fato que a sociedade anda muito dividida. E tem ocorrido aqui. Há usuários com visões diferentes sobre o site.

A SE não têm dado a mesma atenção ao SOpt que antes. E talvez até seja bom assim, mas talvez não.

Bom conteúdo tem ficado enterrado no meio de uma quantidade grande conteúdo fraco. Recompensas só para destacar conteúdo tem surtido efeito bem pequeno, tenho até atraído negativos pra mim por colocar essas recompensas.

A impressão que tenho é que há uma volume grande de pessoas jogando contra, só pensando em si.

## Dúvidas

Então venho aqui pedir ajuda a vocês, já que a situação hoje é praticamente de termos um site diferente do que havia há 2 anos quando fui eleito.

Primeiro gostaria que ajudassem a apontar problemas que eu não coloquei aqui.
Queria que apontassem soluções reais para isto.

Concordam comigo? Em que partes discorda?

Será que a experiência de fazer conteúdo de qualidade falhou? Não é o que as pessoas querem?

A gamificação está fazendo o comportamento ser ruim e usuários agirem só com base no que podem ganhar de pontos e medalhas?

Podemos dar alguma solução para o que expus?

Vocês acham que devemos mudar nossa postura? O site deve ter seus objetivos mudados?

Precisamos fazer algo? Ou melhor "aceitar que dói menos"?

O que os moderadores podem fazer? Especialmente eu.

O que vocês podem fazer? Farão?

O que gostaria que mudasse que não depende de você?

Se eu resolver mudar em, relação ao que disse que faria quando fui eleito devo deixar a moderação?

O que você faria se o site mantiver a linha de degradação das perguntas. As respostas entram na questão para você?

Enfim, qual sua opinião sobre isto, e o que pode ser feito?

Preciso de subsídios porque não sei bem como lidar com esta nova situação. Estou apontando problemas para ver se existe solução, boa ou ruim. Ficar calado me daria menos trabalho.

---

Desde que postei isso a situação piorou. Tem dia que eu fechou ou negativo 80/90% das perguntas que eu leio. É desmotivador e é trágico para nossa indústria que temos tanta gente que sequer consegue formular uma dúvida minimamente compreensível. Não é questão de não saber programar, de não entender as regras do site ou qualquer coisa mais avançada, é analfabetismo funcional. Me desculpe o desabafo, mas está dando muito trabalho lidar com algo tão lamentável.

Comment: A respeito do "muitos casos é um enunciado de exercício largado ou um "como faz tal coisa" sem nenhum esforço"  acreditava que o melhor a se fazer é talvez fosse explicar o problema, mas não propriamente resolve-lo. Para a pessoa tentar se esforçar e resolver o próprio.

Comment: @YODA É uma possibilidade sim, mas resolve o problema que temos aqui? As pessoas estão capacitadas a realizar isso? Ou só termos respostas piores. Já sabemos que em geral não é o que a pessoa está esperando. Já vi caso da pessoa criticar a pessoa ter postado algo que não é o código pronto. EM muitos casos um posta como chegar na solução e outro posta a solução, muitas vezes errada porque sequer dá para saber se é aquilo, adivinha qual é aceita? É isso que que queremos aqui?

Comment: Boa parte do que é feito certo é feito por uma minoria, poucos mesmo, que geralmente vão se cansando, outros a margem as vezes colaboram orientando, mas comentem gafes, como atuar e avaliações do qual não detém o conhecimento necessário e soltam pérolas, principalmente na fila de analise, fora os comentários que levam os APs a entenderem o site como um tipo de suporte técnico, inclusive é por este motivo que evito usar o chat gerado automaticamente para falar com APs cujo as perguntas sejam problemáticas, porque isso causa mais a sensação de suporte, mas infelizmente vejo uma duzia de...

Comment: ...usuários que o fazem, transformam o site e um tipo de suporte, esbravejam que estão ajudando, causam uma sensação aos que são novos, ou aqueles que repetem o mesmo de que eles não tem obrigação a nada já que sempre vai ter um prestativo que vai entrar no chat e perguntar detalhe a detalhe até entender de fato o problema, então creio que em parte o problema é esse mal habito causado por essa turminha do barulho. Querem "ajudar", mas não sabem como orientar e levam outros usuários a entender que eles não tem obrigação de fornecer algo concreto diretamente na pergunta.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7160/64969 ; essa primeira pergunta aqui no meta foi um indicativo desse problema. Parece que há sazonalidade de piora acentuada, normalmente associada ao período de avaliações finais e férias acadêmicas. Já é o terceiro ciclo que eu vejo aqui, pelo menos assim me fala a memória. No que eu tenho observado, o ciclo passado (o atual ainda não terminou) trouxe uma sequela maior do que o primeiro que eu vira: a qualidade das perguntas sofreu uma queda e não subiu à margem anterior. Infelizmente, não tenho nenhuma sugestão ainda...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ali foi caso isolado. O que me parece é que há um enxurrada de pessoas que acreditaram na falácia que qualquer um pode programar e começaram tentar do jeito que provavelmente tentaram fazer qualquer coisa a vida toda, ou seja, sem nenhum comprometimento, sem aprender o que vem antes, só querem ver o resultado e as pessoas à sua volta que se adaptem à sua necessidade, e quem não o fizer é ruim. Sinceramente não estou vendo saída. Eu quero ajudar quem tem vontade, não ser babá de gente sem condições.

Comment: O volume de usuários novos preguiçosos aumentou muito e solucionar um problema que depende dessas pessoas é bem complicado. No meu ponto de vista, temos que quebrar este ciclo ruim que esta se formando, isso tem que ser através de usuários que já estão há algum tempo no site, eles tem que mostrar o caminho da *moderação*, não só focar nas perguntas ou nas respostas, tem que mostrar para os novos usuários que eles também vão ser moderadores e que a participação deles vai ajudar o site a crescer. Acho que o problema esta na nossa moderação como um todo, na forma como estamos moderando o site...

Comment: ... e como nos dirigimos para conversas com usuários novos, e quais ações devem ser tomadas para melhorar a postura e o conteúdo deles. A moderação é o sucesso do SOpt, e talvez seja necessário que ela se adapte a esta nova geração de novatos. Aqui todo mundo é moderador!

Comment: @gato, o problema que estes usuários costumam ser em sua imensa maioria *hit and run*, as vezes até correm antes de ter a resposta. Poucos voltam para mais que 2 ou 3 perguntas, muitas vezes pela impedância de objetivos entre eles e os objetivos do site. Raríssimo os que se tornam usuários de fato. nem reclamei dos usuários que fazem lambança o tempo todo, esse até é possível fazer o que você falou, embora alguns sejam teimosos. Agora me diga uma coisa, você será um dos que ficarão o dia todo pegando na mão e ensinando escrever, sem sequer ter o reconhecimento, como costuma acontecer?

Comment: Acredito que você poderia adicionar o link daquele novo passo a passo do SOen que fizeram para perguntas de iniciantes. Achei uma ótima ideia quem é "novato" no site passar por um tutorial antes de realizar perguntas. Deve estar em fase de testes ainda e ajudaria a resolver parte dos problemas. Claro que não todos. Vi no SOen que criaram alguns comentários prontos (bem curto e grosso) para estes tipos de perguntas, como: o SO não é um site de programação grátis sem nenhum esforço, favor ler tais metas... [Relacionado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6598/75104)

Comment: Uma comunidade espelha o que são a maioria dos seus constituintes/participantes. Se ela não limita, à partida, quem pode participar é possível que novos participantes não sigam as regras. A obrigação de ler um tutorial antes de poder perguntar/responder seria algo que, longe de resolver todos os problemas, ajudaria a triar(quem não ler não participa) e a "educar" novos usuários.

Comment: Uma coisa eu tenho a certeza: o SO será o que os "donos" dele quiserem que seja. Não adianta nós tentarmos mudar as coisas porque o que interessa é "quanto mais perguntas/resposta/participantes melhor".

Comment: Creio que a funcionalidade de "assistente" (Wizard) do SO vai ajudar um pouco na qualidade das perguntas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard. Achei estranho ninguém ter citado ela aqui ainda. Post do SO Meta sobre o Wizard: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype. Com relação aos demais problemas, vou pensar um pouco aqui e ver se posso contribuir em algo em uma resposta.

Comment: @danieltakeshi não está disponível para o SOpt e acho que precisamos mais que o SOen.

Comment: @ramaral eu acho que isto é algo que a SE poderia fazer, mas já sabemos que não o fará. De fato a SE está ciente disto aqui e irá falar algo se não publicamente, pelo menos terá uma posição. Justamente pelo que você disse que eu os acionei. Parece que estão mais preocupados em resolver um problema minúsculo e não fazem o que precisa para resolver o problema enorme que tem no foco da atividade, o problema minúsculo é secundário.

Comment: Li no Tweeter, será verdade? `"Nothing works better than just improving your product." - Joel Spolsky`

Comment: @Maniero Julgo que é mas não é absoluta, li não sei onde que "o produto deve ajustar-se ao que os clientes querem".

Comment: @ramaral quem são os clientes?

Comment: Não consigo deixar de comentar que também noto que o nivel de comprometimento dos novos usuários esta cada vez menor,e a roçar o 0 mesmo. E no fim acho que nem mesmo a SE quer atrair esses usuários. Torna-se um problema dificil de resolver.

Comment: @Maniero Talvez mercado seja a palavra mais adequada. A pergunta é retórica, onde quer chegar(ou que eu chegue) com ela?  "improving your product", o que é *improving*? Qual o seu propósito? O que quis dizer com o meu comentário é que *improving* não pode apenas ser entendido como "com mais qualidade".

Comment: Por mais que a comunidade pregue que a qualidade das perguntas é baixa há pouco que pode ser feito para resolver um problema para um novato. Nao há nenhum substituto para aprendizagem por experiência. Novos utilizadores nunca vao fazer boas perguntas logo no inicio. Eu já acho durante um bom tempo que o SOEN nao é um lugar bom para fazer perguntas, mas axo que é um lugar bom para ver perguntas existentes. Fazer um pergunta relevante é linearmente mais complicado consoante o tempo passa.

Comment: Concordo com o @BrunoCosta que novatos fazendo perguntas ruins sempre vão existir, e para estes casos, talvez seja melhor educar e mostrar como melhorar as perguntas (por mais cansativo que seja). [Criei uma pergunta aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7170/112052) que vai nessa linha de tentar ajudar os iniciantes de alguma forma

Comment: Outro problema que piora isso é fornecer código "prontinho" pra essas perguntas. Coisas do tipo "preciso de um código pra fazer XXX", ai como é simples, já vem alguém colocando código lá, em vez de orientar e incentivar o usuário quem perguntou a procurar fragmentos pra sua dúvida em perguntas diferentes, ou ler um tutorial, assistir um vídeo... isso só incentiva a qualidade baixa das perguntas e dos desenvolvedores que está ai chegando no mercado (que depois reclamam da carreira, salários, etc...)

Comment: @Isac Você tem razão, mas tenho minhas dúvidas se não querem mesmo, vamos ver. O que me impressiona é o tempo gasto para fazer um wizard quase tolo e que ajuda pouco. Muito discurso de ouvir a comunidade, e ações que só olham o sai de lá de dentro. Eles já cometeram tantos erros e ainda acham que só eles entendem o que acontece.

Comment: @RicardoPontual é exatamente isto, muitas perguntas precisam ser respondidas porque se você não sabe onde quer chegar qualquer caminho é errado.

Comment: @BrunoCosta mas ainda pode ser feito algo, tanto que estão fazendo algo, só acho pouco. Pode criar barreira para a pessoa fazer a primeira pergunta e facilitar as pessoas ajudarem que ele melhore nas seguintes. Isto afastará algumas pessoas, que ótimo, essas não deveriam ser bem vindas.

Comment: @hkotsubo isso ignora muito do que eu disse.

Comment: @RicardoPontual bem dito, é o que eu falei da gamificação.

Comment: @Maniero exatamente, se o usuário sempre achar alguma resposta, ele nunca vai se esforçar pra melhorar a pergunta, pesquisar, etc... o sistema de pontuação favorece isso, mas a resposta é consequência, o problema são as perguntas, mais importante se atentar nisso. Agora como resolver não sei, ser muito rígido é meio complicado, isso porque se observar a "hostilidade" que tem no SO, seja nos votos ou nos comentários ácidos que tem por lá, vai ver que aqui o ambiente é mais amistoso, e gosto disso, precisa achar um meio termo mas acredito q precisamos pensar em como tratar essas perguntas

Comment: @RicardoPontual hostilidade não, mas precisamos ter maneiras fáceis de ajudar, se tiver que ficar com se fosse um fórum eu acho que foge do objetivo do site que é o que afastou muitos, inclusive flanado com outras pessoas fora do site que dizem que perde-se muito tempo para ajudar quem não quer ser ajudado de fato. A pessoa tem mais o que fazer e vai fazer em vez de ficar aqui.

Comment: @Maniero sou novata, e sempre soube da existência do SO, mas sempre usei apenas para consultas em meus desenvolvimentos. Agora estou tentando interagir um pouco mais por aqui, editando, respondendo... Não sei se é o caso de elaborar outra pergunta aqui no meta para discussão, mas é sobre o mesmo assunto. Existe muita explicação sobre funcionamento do SOpt para novatos, existe um "tour", mas e se existisse um teste básico para fazer a primeira pergunta, tipo um questionário para validar um "conhecimento básico"? Essas possíveis alterações, dependem de moderadores ou do próprio SE?

Comment: @Melissa eu acharia ótimo, mas a premissa da SE é que deve ser o mais fácil possível para a pessoa postar a pergunta. Ou seja, é culpa dessa política que estamos tendo esses problemas no volume atual. Estão até fazendo alguma coisa https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/221800, isso é bom, ajuda, mas acho que precisa mais. E olha que nem ligo para quem tem alguma dificuldade de se adaptar no início, o maior problema é p total descomprometimento. E legal que resolveu participar mais. Manda ver, mesmo que erre aqui ou ali, errar não é problema, descompromisso é que é.

Comment: https://www.portalraizes.com/geracao-floco-de-neve/

Comment: Tenho péssimas noticias (é mais opinião minha), vou comentar de forma geral, sem detalhes e sei que muitos não vão acreditar ou vão pensar que estou exagerando, muitas das perguntas que notei é de gente que talvez tenham se interessado por TI recentemente, ou que estão em cursos e/ou faculdade ou querendo virar freelancer, um dos motivos (fora a economia problemática do Brasil que fez as pessoas repensarem) são matérias e reportagens como aquela que te disse outro dia no chat, de programadores de app com menos de um ano que ganham 5 mil reais (que passou em um programa de tv conhecido).

Comment: E só um adendo, também andamos a ter péssimas respostas de forma desenfreada, talvez sejam os que atraem parte da pessoas que andam a fazer perguntas tão ruins.

Comment: Sonho de consumo: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Detecting-unwanted-content-using-machine-assisted-content-moderation?WT.mc_id=dlvr_twitter_ch9

Comment: Bom me lembro a primeira vez que fui no meta, fui muito bem atendido e falaram que aqui era o lugar correto para falar de postagens fechadas e perguntas mal feitas. Me ajudaram esclareceram e foram muito bem educados. Agora se eu faço uma pergunta no meta, as pessoas caem em cima. De uma comunidade de programadores, parece que virou uma seleção de quem diz ou não quem é programador. Sendo que tem muitos programadores mais experientes que não usam a comunidade. Na comunidade em inglês eu posso fazer uma pergunta como: Como utilizar a biblioteca X? As pessoas respondem e não negativam.

Comment: @FelipeJorge em geral as pessoas dizem o oposto, que lá quase nada pode ser perguntado. E não achei essa sua pergunta lá. Se fizer perguntas genuínas aqui não tem problema, se fala de algo sem fundamento, se posta só para fazer ataques, aí não será bem recebida mesmo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345940/how-import-acknowledgingconsumerawaremessagelistener

Acredito que se eu fizesse esta pergunta aqui iriam, falar: Me de mais detalhes, isto é muito genérico, muito simples, ou você não entendeu como a comunidade funciona... Acho que a comunidade em inglês é bem mais tranquilo atualmente, pelo menos este caso foi uma boa experiência.

Comment: O problema de novos usuários é que não sabem/entendem que editar as perguntas ajuda. E ao receberem comentários a dizer para especificarem/elaborarem como são usuários novos pensam simplesmente ninguém quer ajudar por isso tentam criar uma pergunta nova e veêm que só podem fazer uma a cada tantos dias e como a pergunta que fizeram têm muita atenção negativa desistem da pergunta e do site.
Devia tentar fazer com que os utilizadores novos entenderem a importância de editar as perguntas com mais detalhes e corrigir.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Há várias coisas diferentes na sua pergunta, então vamos por partes. Levei uns dois dias redigindo isso tudo e está uma colcha de retalhos, mas estou cansado demais para fechar todos os detalhes necessários e portanto decidi postar mesmo assim.

### 90%

Há uma teoria que diz que 90% de qualquer coisa é porcaria. 90% aqui no Stack Overflow não poderia ser diferente, mesmo com os mecanismos que temos para controle de qualidade.

Todos os sites da SE apresentam uma boa dose de perguntas de baixa qualidade. Da parte dos novatos, poucos são os que sabem formatar as perguntas adequadamente e fazer uma boa pergunta inicialmente (curiosamente, hoje eu vi na fila de análise de primeiras publicações, um usuário novo que fez uma pergunta de qualidade razoável e corretamente formatada, então ainda temos esperanças).

Esse problema não é nada novo e boa parte das causas são bem conhecidas.

### Usuários que não entendem como o SOpt funciona

Isso pode parecer ser chover no molhado, mas há uma informação nova aqui: Esse problema está piorando!

Não é novidade que pessoas que vem fazer perguntas aqui, muitas vezes não tem conhecimento o suficiente para entender as regras da comunidade, estando acostumadas ao formato dos fóruns, do yahuim respostas, ou até mesmo o pior e mais horroroso formato de todos: as listas de e-mail.

No entanto, desde que o SOen ou mesmo o SOpt surgiu, esse problema piorou bastante, pois hoje os usuários partem de um formato do facebook, whatsapp, telegram e slack. O formato de um fórum é um intermediário entre o formato da SE e o do whatsapp. Assim sendo, se o usuário que saia do fórum para vir para cá já tinha dificuldade de se adaptar às regras da comunidade, o usuário que vem do whatsapp tem ainda mais dificuldade.

Para quem vem de um grupo do whatsapp ou do slack e entra no SOpt, coisas como títulos bem formados (ou mesmo necessidade de existir um título), editar mensagens, votar em perguntas ou respostas, reputação, tags, postar código como texto ao invés de imagens (tente digitar um código-fonte longo em um grupo do whatsapp), MCVE, fechamento de perguntas, não permitir perguntas de opinião ou enquetes, etc, parecem ser regras e conceitos alienígenas e lunáticos. Poucos desses usuários conseguem se adaptar ou entender as regras.

No whatsapp ou no slack, o formato é de um grande chat onde entra de tudo, não muito diferente do nosso próprio chat, porém com ainda menos regras. Se antes os usuários novos postavam perguntas imaginando que isso daqui era um fórum, agora eles estão postando perguntas novas como se isso fosse um chat.

### Grandes avisos invisíveis

Muitas dessas péssimas perguntas são fechadas. Um box amarelo bem grande aparece abaixo da pergunta. No entanto, esse box amarelo tem um problema: **Ele tem uma aparência de publicidade textual.**

Na internet, somos bombardeados constantemente com uma grande dose de informações inúteis em forma de publicidade muito maior do que um cérebro humano é capaz de processar. Como essas informações são quase sempre totalmente inúteis, nosso cérebro aprende a ignorá-las, afinal de contas, quem quer que esteja disposto a prestar atenção em todo o tipo de porcaria que fica pulando na tela do navegador, vai rapidamente enlouquecer ou no mínimo não conseguirá se concentrar em fazer nada de produtivo. Dessa forma, o cérebro de boa parte dos nossos usuários está treinado em ignorar o box amarelo de fechamento da pergunta. O nome desse fenômeno é chamado de [**banner blindness** ou **ad blindness**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness).

Esse problema não se limita apenas ao box amarelo de fechamento de perguntas. Quando você vai fazer uma pergunta, um box aparece ao lado direito explicando um pouco sobre como perguntar. Pois bem, **eu levei quase dois anos para perceber aquele box ali.** O motivo disso é que meu cérebro já estava treinado a ignorar esse tipo de informação. Hoje, pensando nesse problema específico, abri a fila de análise e percebi o box ali também. Embora já tenha visto aquele box milhares de vezes, percebi que havia muitos anos que eu não lia o que nele estava escrito.

### Fila de análise

O formato da fila de análises não ajuda muito. Na análise de perguntas, as respostas existententes não são mostradas. Na análise de respostas, as demais respostas também não são mostradas. Com isso, muitas vezes é necessário abrir a pergunta em questão para ver o contexto como um todo. Após ser tomada uma decisão na fila de análise ("Parece OK", "Fechar", "Deixar fechada", "Reabrir", "Recomendar exclusão", "Pular", etc), ela já carrega outra pergunta sem dar oportunidade de postar comentários mais detalhados.

Acredito que na fila de análise, uma UI que incentivasse visualizar o contexto da pergunta inteira incluindo todas as respostas e incentivasse comentários, ajudaria muito. Eu acredito que os comentários são de fundamental importância para o bom funcionamento do Q&A no formato da SE, mas que a SE não lhes dá o devido valor.

E uma coisa um tanto rara, mas acontece de vez em quando comigo, é pegar uma pergunta na fila de análise e eu não apenas revisar ela, como também ir lá respondê-la. Mas a UI da fila de análise não foi feita pensando-se em responder perguntas. Talvez as coisas mudariam um pouco se "Postar uma resposta" fosse uma alternativa válida de revisar algo na fila de análise.

Ficar pendurado nas filas de análise é algo muito chato de se fazer e, com exceção do Articuno e do Maniero, é muito difícil se ter saco para ficar pendurado nelas por meses e meses a fio. Talvez essa seja a parte onde umas ideias para se refrescar e revitalizar o ambiente se faça necessário.

### Usuários de saco cheio

Ficar revisando perguntas e respostas mal elaboradas é um porre. Ainda mais se o autor da pergunta/resposta for alguém que já causou problemas. A gamificação até estimula isso um pouco, mas só um pouco e só até certo ponto. Rapidamente se chega a um ponto onde não há nada além do dever e do autosacrifício.

Frequentemente vejo perguntas e respostas onde eu até sei onde estão os problemas, sei o que poderia ser feito para ajudar o autor, ou perguntas complexas que eu até sei como responder, mas que são muito trabalhosos para isso. Em especial, há dias onde tenho pouco tempo para isso, ou onde estou muito cansado ou com dor-de-cabeça, que sinceramente desanima.

Há perguntas que são digamos *tóxicas*, que desanimam bastante de se ver, mas que não são coisas que mereçam sinalização ou fechamento imediato. Nesses casos aí, a menos que eu esteja em um dia muito bom, não dá nenhuma vontade de meter a mão porque é confusão e dor-de-cabeça na certa. O problema é que às vezes parece que os próprios moderadores tem essa mesma impressão que eu tenho. Ou então preferem apenas fechar a pergunta monocraticamente sem maiores comentários e resolve-se o pepino sem maiores dificuldades. Embora essa solução seja a melhor para a sanidade mental de todos a curto prazo, acho que ela é prejudicial à comunidade em longo prazo.

Sempre temos um grande fluxo de usuários novos, muitos dos quais postam uma ou duas perguntas e não voltam nunca mais. Isso não é nem nunca foi um problema novo e provavelmente trata-se de algo que nunca será resolvido. Entretanto o problema são os usuários já estabelecidos.

## Comentários automáticos e motivos de fechamento

Por fim, acho que uma revisão dos motivos de fechamento e dos comentários automáticos pode melhorar um pouco as coisas. A SE preza por haver um número pequeno de razões em ambos os casos. Embora certamente haver dezenas e dezenas de motivos para se escolher seja péssimo, precisamos levar em conta de que razões muito genéricas e amplas não ajudam muito e que as pessoas que usam essas ferramentas são usuários experientes. Assim sendo, eu poderia sugerir melhores razões de sinalização e fechamento.

Para ser mais específico:

> **fora do escopo** - Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.

Essa razão precisa ser revista. Uma coisa é um erro de digitação bobo do tipo que faltou um ponto-e-vírgula, e isso não tem nada a ver com MCVE. Outra coisa bem diferente é quando a pessoa posta um trecho de código incompleto com um monte de coisas que vem do nada e vão para lugar nenhum. Ter essas duas razões de fechamento na mesma mensagem é no mínimo confuso. Classificá-las como "fora do escopo" também não faz sentido, pois a maioria das perguntas onde isso se aplica são perguntas de programação que de fato estão no escopo do site.

> **não está clara o suficiente** - Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Isso daqui tende a abarcar dois casos diferentes. O primeiro é [aquelas  perguntas redigidas de forma extremamente superficial](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/132). O segundo é quando a pergunta de fato tem código, mensagens de erro e etc, mas tem um monte de pontas soltas e valeria recomendar o MCVE (e nesses casos fico em dúvida entre isso e o outro motivo que elucidei acima).

> **ampla demais** - Limite a pergunta a um problema específico, e forneça detalhes suficientes para conseguir uma resposta adequada. Evite fazer várias perguntas ao mesmo tempo. Para ajuda sobre como esclarecer a pergunta, veja Como Perguntar

Na maioria das perguntas que são amplas demais, não é nem questão de limitar, nem fornecer detalhes o suficientes. e nem de serem várias perguntas ao mesmo tempo. Por exemplo, na pergunta "*Como se faz para programar em C++?*", só há uma pergunta. Se você pedir para o usuário dar mais detalhes, ele vai dizer que é porque o fulano amigo dele o levou para uma reunião na empresa XPTO onde o web designer falou que o professor está procurando um cara que blablabla, mas nada disso ajuda a definir melhor a pergunta. Se você pedir para ele limitar o problema, ele provavelmente vai responder que o limite dele é duas semanas ou alguma outra coisa que não ajuda em nada. O problema é que boa parte dos usuários não entendem o porquê da pergunta ser ampla demais e não tem a menor ideia de como resolver isso.

> **Isto é comentário sobre outra publicação, não uma resposta** -
>   “Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver reputação suficiente, você vai poder deixar comentários em qualquer post mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou.”

Para usuários que já tiverem reputação suficiente, isso daqui deveria ser redigido de forma diferente. Para os que não têm reputação suficiente, isso daqui soa um tanto agressivo, mais ou menos como "*você não é bem-vindo aqui*". Ainda mais considerando que algumas das respostas que recebem isso estão em cima da linha entre respostas de baixa qualidade e comentários como resposta, mas que seus autores postaram imaginando estar respondendo à pergunta.

> Este é um comentário de “agradecimento”
>   “Não adicione "obrigado" como resposta. Quando tiver pontos de reputação suficientes, você poderá votar a favor de perguntas e respostas que considerar úteis.”

Nem sempre o texto é exatamente "*obrigado*" e já vi gente ficando confusa por causa disso. Talvez redigir isso como "*Não adicione agradecimentos como resposta*". Além disso, isso também não considera a reputação do autor da resposta.

Comment: Não sei se todos os sites são assim. O assunto tem a ver, e vivemos uma realidade de pessoas sem qualquer preparado mínimo para fazer algo minimamente qualificado achando que acharam o profissão de ouro. Certamente tem alguns usuários bons, mesmo novatos. O volume atual é novo, não o problema. E a apatia da comunidade. Eu acho que nem é o problema da pessoa achar que aqui é um fórum, até é, mas agora está aparecendo que nem isso sabe, a esculhambação passou ser total. Concordo com a visão sobre os tipos de sites/apps. Recentemente me colocaram em um grupo "técnico" de WA e é terrível...

Comment: ...perda de tempo total. `Poucos desses usuários conseguem se adaptar ou entender as regras` ou seja, estamos perdendo o nosso tempo com gente que nunca será programador. E eu penso em ter alguma coisa pronta pra demonstrar isso pras essas pessoas. Algo bem feito, curado pela comunidade e que ajude o cara ter uma visão diferente do que ele está fazendo não só no site, mas na vida dele. Pode ser a melhor coisa que podemos fazer para estas pessoas, e é o que mais quero. Mas terão aqueles que insistirão no "bumba meu boi". E quem insistir nisso eu sou favorável não ter dó.

Comment: `Ele tem uma aparência de publicidade textual`, sim, ele precisa de um *overhaul*, não só nesse aspecto e não só isto. Eu até hoje não entendi o que a pessoas especialista em UX da SE faz, é como acontecia com nosso CM aqui que a gente nunca entendeu o que (não) fazia. O wizard pode ajudar, mas achei ele tão bobinho, meses, quase anos de trabalho para um resultado medíocre. As filas têm esse problema e tem o problema difícil de resolver que é premiar que é atuante e punir que só faz pelo prêmio. Convenhamos, a SE não está olhando para os vários problemas que temos.

Comment: Muito discurso de melhoria, de ouvir a comunidade, mas é só pro forma sempre, no fim fazem do jeito que querem, como o @ramaral disse. Eu não penduro muito na fila mais não, agora vou quase que só na página de perguntas, não dá. O que faço é usar a fila de sinalizações que vão pros moderadores, nem vou falar muito disso...

Comment: Reproduzo suas palavras sobre tentar ajudar usuários, as vezes até posto um comentário, mas não dá para fazer muito mais com o volume tão grande e tão pouca gente querendo ajudar (o que eu entendo, não estou reclamando disso), aí tem gente que acha que é má vontade (pra falar a verdade este tipo de coisa desmotiva, você dá o sangue pra ouvir esse tipo de crítica, que reclame se outras coisas). Eu tenho fechado ou negativo sem maiores atenções, dado o volume. Tem casos que a coisa "me chama" e até tento ajudar um pouco mais. Eu espero que alguém possa ajudar mais.

Comment: Vez ou outra acontece, e o problema é resolvido, e se eu ver eu reabro. Aí podemos começar falar sobre notificações que o sistema não faz e deveria, pelo menos opcionalmente. "Embora essa solução seja a melhor para a sanidade mental de todos a curto prazo, acho que ela é prejudicial à comunidade em longo prazo", concordo, mas é o que tem pra hoje. Precisamos de melhores ferramentas para evitar os problemas e solucioná-los melhor de forma mais fácil. Temo que já seja um pouco tarde demais pra muita gente que já perderam a sanidade, mas ainda pode ser feito algo.

Comment: O que me impressiona é que isto foi dito tantas vezes, e sempre foi ignorado. Tem gente que defendia ajudar tanto, de todos colocarem um esforço tremendo para o bem da comunidade, mas ajudar que é bom... Eu acho que o problema do usuário *hit and run* não é tão importante se a decisão é não perder tempo com eles. Essas mudanças mais específicas no sistema eu até quero ver em outro post dedicado a isto. E será uma das últimas tentativas que farei. Só para expor um pouco a ideia q tenho (não q precisa ser exatamente assim), mas algumas outras coisas precisam mudar pra evitar outros problemas:

Comment: @Maniero Quanto a afirmação de que todos podem ser programadores, isso é tão verdadeiro quanto a afirmação que todos podem ser médicos, ou que todos podem ser advogados, ou que todos podem ser astronautas - simplesmente é falso. No entanto, muitos vão tentar e ficar pelo caminho, e parte desse caminho pode passar no SOpt.

Comment: DUP -> faz merge, mesmo que de uma forma diferente; OFF -> (só as obviamente off, o q pode incluir algo de opinião ou formato não aceito) remove, com um tempo para a pessoa acertar, depois vai, sem perdão, sem exceção; BAD -> fecha e talvez remove no futuro, e aqui vai um monte de motivos mais específicos pra ajudar. Concordo com seus pontos. Na verdade estamos falando de obviedades que não se faz nada não sei porque. Você tocou na ponta do iceberg :) :( Essa cisa do obrigado deve cair, porque "agora" pode fazer isso. Obrigado pela resposta, espero que tudo isso sirva pra algo melhorar.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é mais fácil um médico virar programador do que um programador virar médico, será que programação não é para todos? Não é algo tão difícil. Apesar de algumas empresas precisar de um diploma para entrar, algumas só querem saber se você sabe programar. Na faculdade você aprende uma coisa, no mercado de trabalho é completamente diferente...  O fato de um Dentista parar que está fazendo e começar a trabalhar de desenvolvedor de game indie e ter uma carreira de sucesso é a prova de que qualquer um pode se tornar um programador. Um dia programação vai ser tão básico quanto escrever.

Comment: @FelipeJorge Já conheci pessoas que não podem virar programador de jeito nenhum, como um indivíduo que conheci que mesmo trabalhando com programação por mais de 15 anos, não conseguia fazer um único if corretamente sem gambiarrizar tudo ao extremo. Quanto ao fato de um dia programação ser tão básico quanto escrever, me lembra a seguinte frase de Bjarne Stroustrup, criador do C++: "*I have always wished for my computer to be as easy to use as my telephone; my wish has come true because I can no longer figure out how to use my telephone.*"

Comment: Se ele trabalha com programação a 15 anos ele é de fato um programador. Agora se ele faz o trabalho direito ou se ele é experiente é outra história. Na verdade não sei se você é apto em dizer quem é programador ou não. Muitas vezes o cara faz gambiarra mas deve ter feito e entregado mais serviços do que você... Eu também já fiz técnico, hoje sou formado e faço pós graduação. O que eu vejo na comunidade são bastante gente que sabe programar esculachando gente que está aprendendo agora, mas nunca fez um site, sistema ou aplicativo para ninguém... Nem mesmo trabalham em uma empresa de TI...

Comment: @FelipeJorge Eu sei o que o cara fez porque quem teve que refazer tudo do zero depois fui eu.

Answer (score 17):

O SO é um negócio e o seu sucesso depende do número de participantes.

A qualidade das perguntas e respostas é importante mas está subordinada a essa realidade.

> Concordam comigo? Em que partes discorda?

Concordo com tudo.

> Será que a experiência de fazer conteúdo de qualidade falhou? Não é o que as pessoas querem?

Falha em consequência da necessidade de ter de haver muitos usuários. O que a maioria quer é só ter o seu problema resolvido(help desk).

> A gamificação está fazendo o comportamento ser ruim e usuários agirem só com base no que podem ganhar de pontos e medalhas?

A gamificação é boa mas como tudo tem dois lados.
Estando ela ligada à classificação do conteúdo tem efeitos perversos nessa classificação. Não vejo como resolver.

> Podemos dar alguma solução para o que expus?
>
> Vocês acham que devemos mudar nossa postura? O site deve ter seus objetivos mudados?
>
> Precisamos fazer algo? Ou melhor "aceitar que dói menos"?
>
> O que os moderadores podem fazer? Especialmente eu.

Podemos, o problema é se queremos(a SE quer?).
Se queremos, a postura dos moderadores tem de mudar. Em vez de apenas moderadores terão de passar a ser mais [zeladores](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/zelador).
Ou disponibilizar melhores/eficazes ferramentas a **alguns** dos outros utilizadores.
Se não, é melhor mudar os objectivos e "aceitar que dói menos".

Temos de ter presente que tudo o que for feito para melhorar o conteúdo terá reflexo no número de perguntas e participantes.

> O que vocês podem fazer? Farão?

Com as ferramentas disponíveis pouco mais posso fazer. É certo que cada vez menos faço: incluo-me no grupo "de muitos usuários que já cansaram de arrumar tantos problemas, de ficar tentando enxugar gelo, sem resultado."
Quando verificar que há *de facto* vontade de mudar, o que passa por melhores ferramentas, estou disposto a ajudar.

> O que gostaria que mudasse que não depende de você?

Que de uma vez por todas a SE clarificasse o que quer: quantidade, qualidade ou deixar andar.
Se quer qualidade que disponibilize melhores e eficazes ferramentas de moderação e classificação do conteúdo.

> Se eu resolver mudar em, relação ao que disse que faria quando fui eleito devo deixar a moderação?

Sim, você e os outros.
Não que isso vá resolver o problema da moderação, outros serão eleitos...

Correndo o risco de ser injusto, já que pode haver trabalho vosso nos bastidores que desconheço, do que me é dado ver a vossa actuação é <s>praticamente nula</s> muito reduzida.

> O que você faria se o site mantiver a linha de degradação das perguntas. As respostas entram na questão para você?

A tendência é participar cada vez menos. Cada vez há menos perguntas que valham uma resposta.

Comment: Não querendo bancar "advogado do diabo", até porque cada um sabe por si o que faz por aqui, mas acho que a maioria dos atos de moderadores passam despercebidos por nós, exceto as ferramentas que já temos acesso como fechamentos. Eu vejo muita coisa acontecer como resultado de ação deles, exemplo são banimentos de usuários que insistem em tentar burlar as ferramentas do site, e não é pouco, eu com meu pouco acesso já presenciei ao menos uns 10 banimentos por isso. Sem contar nas sinalizações atendidas. Eu costumo acompanhar as que faço pra ver se de fato eu fiz bem ou me equivoquei[...]

Comment: [...] e usar como aprendizado pra casos futuros. Nos demais pontos, eu concordo com você, fica desgastante mesmo com o tempo e a gente vai desanimando.

Comment: Estamos tendo mais usuários *hit and run*, não sei se isto é bom. Nada contra ver a pessoa querer ver só seu problema resolvido, mas ela precisa se esforçar. Até se o serviço fosse pago não é certo o que elas fazem. Eu até vejo como resolver o problema do exagero na gamificação, mas não cabe a nós. Quando fala de moderadores serem zeladores, está falando dos eleitos ou de todos? É justo pedir isto? Concordo que as ferramentas são limitadores e coloca fardo em todos. `Que de uma vez por todas a SO clarificasse o que quer`, o ponto fundamental. Excelente reposta, que bom que gastou um tempo. Obg

Comment: `Correndo o risco de ser injusto, já que pode haver trabalho vosso nos bastidores que desconheço, do que me é dado ver a vossa actuação é praticamente nula muito reduzida.` não sei se entendi exatamente do que está falando aqui, pode detalhar mais?

Comment: @Articuno não sei o que ramaral quis dizer com isso, e pedi pra esclarecer, e de fato tem muita coisa que não aparece nem se procurar muito, mesmo de quem é mais atento como você e outros. Em muitos casos nem há uma ação real por falta de condições, mas gasta-se tempo tentando resolver.

Comment: @Maniero ***"está falando dos eleitos ou de todos"***: Refiro-me a todos, a não ser que o comprometimento dos primeiros seja diferente do dos segundos. ***"do que me é dado ver a vossa actuação ..."***: Refiro-me ao pouco uso do "martelo" porque *"Fechamentos podem ajudar, mas costumam chegar tarde demais...*".

Comment: @ramaral verdade, tem hora que desanima mesmo, há dias que dá pra fechar uns 70% das perguntas. A comunidade deveria estar fazendo um pouco isso. Há também quem reclame que fecho muito, não é fácil.

Comment: @ramaral O martelo deveria ser uma ferramenta de exceção. Uma comunidade saudável  deveria dar conta sozinha de moderar as coisas mais óbvias.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo, mas *tem a comunidade dado conta sozinha das coisas mais óbvias?*

Comment: Não, não tem dado conta. Esse é o problema mais grave, do meu ponto de vista. Nós moderadores podemos até intervir mais, mesmo desanimados. Mas não me parece uma solução sustentável.

Comment: Eu estou aqui há pouco tempo e estou tentando colaborar com o site, mas realmente não há muitas perguntas que valem a pena...

Answer (score 15):

Pelo que percebo, há vários problemas e muitos deles são compartilhados com o SO e outros são mais exclusivos da nossa comunidade.

Confesso que me passou até um certo desânimo vendo os comentários do pessoal. O pessoal antigo realmente aparenta estar cansado, e o mais engraçado é que eu não compartilho integralmente desta sensação ruim quanto ao que ocorre no site. Será que sou só eu? Claro que há problemas, e muitos deles devem passar desapercebidos pelos usuários que não fazem parte da moderação, então isto pode explicar minha percepção diferente.

Para qualquer mudança, precisamos entender quais ferramentas temos para isto. Não tem como ser muito criativo então, já que ficamos limitados ao que o site oferece aos usuários mais mortais (conforme Ramaral disse).

Vamos separar a discussão por assunto.

## Moderação

Algo que me chamou a atenção é que existem **moderadores inativos** ou com pouca atuação no site. Não conheço as regras do SO quanto a isto, mas a pergunta é: não é possível fazer uma nova eleição e fazer uma renovação deste quadro de moderadores?

Talvez dando uma renovada no pessoal, e dando a oportunidade para aqueles que querem sair saiam de vez, ajudaria a moderação ganhar um ânimo novo.

## Qualidade da pergunta

Felizmente o SO está com um [protótipo de um assistente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard) (um guia passo-a-passo) para que o usuário novato possa se orientar por ele e criar uma pergunta mais compreensível e de melhor qualidade. Vocês podem acompanhar a [discussão no Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype) sobre ele.

A princípio isto vai melhorar a qualidade das perguntas e dar menos trabalho para a moderação e demais usuários que ativamente editam as perguntas dos novatos para deixar elas mais apresentáveis. Infelizmente vamos precisar aguardar isto ir para o SO e depois ir para o SOpt. Será que tem como nossa comunidade participar cobaia do *beta* desta ferramenta?

## Orientar usuários novos

Precisamos ter paciência e boa vontade com os usuários novos, não tem outro jeito. Já vi as histórias de muitos usuários ativos e com pontuação alta no SOpt que começaram com perguntas exatamente como as descritas pelo Maniero no site: cheio de problemas.

Pelo que contato que tenho com o pessoal novo, os que voltam ao site normalmente voltam não cometendo os mesmos erros, e ainda pedindo desculpas quando cometem algum erro. Isto me deixa bem contente, inclusive. Precisamos tratar bem este pessoal para que eles possam ser os futuros usuários ativos do site. Alguns usuários não tem muita salvação mesmo.

## Contribuição de usuários ativos (não moderadores)

Creio que os usuários ativos do site que não participam da moderação (me incluo aqui) podem se dedicar mais a editar perguntas e respostas com problemas, em fazer com as filas de análise girem mais rápido, etc. Isto ajuda a tirar um pouco desta carga da moderação e fazer com que eles se dediquem a assuntos mais importantes. Eu mesmo aumentei minha participação neste sentido nas últimas semanas.

Vou pensar mais um pouco e ver se aparece mais alguma ideia.

Comment: Em relação a "ter paciencia", muitos até tem, mas a má vontade de uma quantidade significativa de usuários que chegam perguntando aqui faz essa paciência se esgotar rapidamente. Mas quanto a valorizar os que vão melhorando, isso é facilmente perceptível pra quem frequenta todo dia, e concordo contigo neste ponto, se há uma minima demonstração de esforço do autor, a gente precisa amplificar isso, pois já é mais que a maioria que chega aqui faz, querendo que a solução caia de para-quedas no colo sem ter que esforçar em nada.

Comment: tem dia que 80% das perguntas são absurdamente ruins. Não estar todo dia o dia todo ajuda não desgastar tanto. O importante é que todos concordam que as ferramentas não ajudam e a SE pouco faz para mudar isso. Gasta-se muito tempo e esforço para escrever um texto que haverá diferenças bruscas de interpretação e causará tantos ou mais problemas que a solução que traz, e não conseguem avançar quase nada em mudança de ferramenta. Sou favorável à moderação ser ainda mais descentralizada em um aspecto, mas reduzida em outro (nem todos conseguem moderar e acabam a causando mais problemas)

Comment: Queria ver quem são as pessoas que se candidatariam em nova eleição. Em geral os que possuem atuação, que poderiam ajudar, que são confiáveis não se mostraram muito interessados. Por isso até temo o que pode acontecer. Mas é algo pode ajudar na solução, se tiver bons candidatos. Não acho que o Wizard será uma ótima solução, mas vai ajudar quando for colocado aqui. Eu acho até que assustará alguns usuários, e isto é bom. Eu acho que somos ideias pra cobaia por ser uma comunidade menor, mas sei qual é o argumento para não usar aqui :)

Comment: Note que minha maior reclamação é do usuário com comprometimento zero. Não me lembro de alguém que virou usuário ativo, e se tiver não deve ser muito mais que 2 ou 3. Problemas na pergunta é uma coisa mais ou menos aceitável. O problema é o total descaso. Não sei se ficou claro na minha "pergunta debate". E essas pessoas não conseguem seguir orientações, por teimosia, falta de capacidade, ou o que seja. Os que se esforçam é outra coisa, dá para lidar com esse tipo, sempre tivemos gente assim, nunca foi tão grande e mais ou menos deu resultado.

Comment: Esse assistente vai ajudar bastante, agora até chegar aqui no SOpt.....

Answer (score 4):

Como um usuário novato nesse momento, vou deixar meus 10 centavos nesse debate também.

Tenho visto algumas atitudes suas na moderação do site que, acredito (e lendo a política de uso do SO), tenham sido equivocadas.

Tudo o que você, Maniero, expôs, está certo no seu ponto de vista. Não é raro (e entendendo sua frustração) entrar no SO do Brasil e encontrar uma perguntas que poderiam ser respondidas com uma googlada bem dada ou a leitura da documentação oficial da linguagem que o cidadão está tentando aprender.

Contudo, como não existem verdades universais, o seu é apenas um ponto de vista. Na minha opinião, por exemplo, não existem "perguntas de baixa qualidade". Toda pergunta é digna de uma resposta e, acredito, são as pessoas que pensam assim que buscam maneiras mais criativas para fazer as mesmas tarefas que, de repente, você só conhece uma única resolução. Se você assistia ao Mundo de Beakman quando mais jovem, acho que sabe do que estou falando. hehe

Você considerar que determinada pergunta não tem a qualidade que deseja demonstra apenas que seu nível naquele aspecto específico é maior do que a pessoa que fez a pergunta. Mas ela pode ter um nível maior que o seu em outro aspecto. Muitas vezes, a maneira como você evidencia a diferença de nível desrespeita a competência do outro e, movido pelo calor do momento, você pode nem se dar conta disso. Acredito que cabe um pouco de humildade nessa situação também, sobretudo, no seu cargo na moderação desse site.

Não tenho o intuito de deslegitimar seu desabafo/proposta de debate mas, de repente, posso abrir os olhos da galera para outra questão que, ao meu ver, está passando despercebida.

Comment: Faltou argumentos, só tem críticas aí, e infundadas, porque eu sempre fui um defensor de responder perguntas bem feitas sobre qualquer assunto, inclusive aqueles que são fáceis de achar no Google, esta é inclusive um preceito do site. E eu respondo muito essas perguntas. A crítica não faz sentido. Estou falando da qualidade das perguntas, em nenhum momento falo das perguntas serem básicas, porque as adoro. Perguntas básicas são as que ensinam e isto é tudo o que quero. Se toda pergunta fosse digna de resposta não teria todas ferramentas que existem para negativar, fechar,sinalizar e remover...

Comment: ...justamente por baixa de qualidade. Então acredito que não leu e entendeu realmente como o site funciona, a documentação e discussões no meta são extensivos quanto a isto, me parece claro que sua interpretação está equivocada quando diz que não existe perguntas de baixa qualidade. Você pode ter sua opinião, mas ela não se sustenta em fatos. E minha atuação é toda em cima de dizer "não sigam receitas de bolo", todos que acompanham o site sabem que sou até chato nisso, que sou muito apegado ao contexto, ao caso concreto, então mais algumas críticas não fazem sentido.

Comment: Então seria bom abir seus olhos para algo que você não percebeu também no seu desabafo. Entendo sua motivação, mas ela usa falsas premissas ou são apenas opiniões. Mas não se preocupe, eu já estou me cansando de ser atacado por fazer justamente o que o site pede, esta é minha última tentativa de ainda manter um pouco da qualidade que tínhamos e agora não tem mais. Infelizmente o SOpt já se tornou um site como outro qualquer, cheio de desinformação, e não tem muito mais o que fazer.

Comment: Creio que vc tem todo direito de dar seu ponto de vista, mas que está cheio de pergunta e resposta de baixa qualidade no site, está. E isso não é opinião, basta analisar os fatores de maneira objetiva. Alguns deles: razão de ter sido feita, jeito de descrever o problema, abrangência, escopo, foco nos problemas relevantes, etc. (é muito mais extenso que isso, mas o que é irrelevante é o "gosto pessoal"). Isso não guarda nenhuma relação com tempo de experiência, tem novato que faz perguntas ótimas, tem "veterano" que só produz lixo. É assim em tudo na vida.

Comment: Aliás, eu ousaria dizer que se tivesse uns 4 mods engajados no site desde o começo filtrando os posts como se filtra agora, e não tivesse tido interferência 'externa' no começo, isso aqui seria muito mais organizado e útil para quem visita.

Comment: Desde 2014 eu alertava para o problema, aqui tem mais detalhes: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2096/70

Comment: Maniero - Ok. Vi que sou voto vencido. De fato, o que expus foi a minha opinião e não cabe, aqui, entrar em uma discussão extensa a respeito. Não levem para o lado pessoal por favor. Elaborei essa opinião comparando o SO em inglês com esse. Já fiz o teste: Se alguém fizer a mesma pergunta nos dois, será tratado mais respeitosamente em inglês do que aqui de um modo geral.

Bacco - Entendi seu ponto de vista e, nesse aspecto, concordamos mesmo. Só acho que há uma diferença entre "Poderia reformular sua pergunta?" e "Pode fazer uma pergunta menos lixo?", entende?

Comment: @illozzaM entendo, e não tentarei entrar no mérito pq sei que a lingua escrita em espaços restritos como é aqui nos faria perdermos muito tempo para afinar detalhes que não são relevantes. Da mesma forma que vc fez um contraponto eu tb fiz ao seu post, mas sempre no intuito de "estressarmos a idéia" e não as pessoas :) - o "embate saudável" faz com que todos os lados aprofundem os pensamentos, prefiro crer que é o seu objetivo, assim como é o meu.

Comment: @illozzaM justamente por não levar para o lado pessoal que estamos aqui. A percepção geral das pessoa que o SOen é bem pior que aqui e fecham tudo e negativam de forma até arbitrária. E o SOen já é tudo agora como um local de conteúdo bom antigo, mas quase nada novo é útil, o que a gente tentou é não deixar acontecer o mesmo aqui. Em geral quando vejo as pessoas falando assim sobre o SOen é só porque ela teve pouca experiência lá, é só porque não dá pra ver tudo como nós que estamos usando lá há 10 anos vimos. Sua visão sobre isso parece ser apenas do buraco da fechadura, não do todo.

Comment: Um ponto importante é que quase todo mundo que defende essas perguntas ruins não querem se dar ao trabalho de ajudar salvá-las, de torná-las com um mínimo de qualidade. Nos raros casos que alguém se mostra interessado em fazer isto a pergunta costuma ter outro destino, se o autor colaborar um pouco.

Comment: Maniero - Pode ser mesmo... Realmente tenho pouca experiência tanto lá quanto aqui. Entendam que sou da turma que aprendeu a programar sozinho em BASIC num TK-90X em meados de 1989 (sem internet). hehe Foi tudo na base de tentativa e erro (de verdade!) e, nessa situação, é normal que tenha passado uma coisa ou outra batido. Agora, no SO, tenho tentado usar com muita moderação porque sei que algumas perguntas mais básicas são incomodativas a algumas pessoas.

Comment: Com isso, estou querendo dizer que, da maneira como aprendi, nunca tive o hábito de fazer perguntas a outras pessoas. Então, pra mim, essa é uma tarefa difícil em determinadas situações.

Comment: Note que ser básica não é defeito não, pergunta básica é super bem vinda, e eu sinto uma falta danada delas. O que acontece é que, por exemplo, tem cara que pega um trabalho que não dá conta, estrutura um código tosco pra tentar fazer o que vendeu pro cliente, acha que no meio da situação um loop num array é a solução pro problema imediato que ele mesmo criou, e vem com uma pergunta sobre esse loop. Aí a gente parte de uma coisa que "parece simples" mas tem toda uma história, ai o resultado nao serve nem pro autor nem pra quem vem depois. E o site vira "suporte", coisa que não é o objetivo.

Comment: Eu comecei com TK-82. Infelizmente você ainda está preso a uma percepção equivocada, perguntas básicas não incomodam, perguntas mal feitas, sem cuidado, com desleixo, com problemas que impedem de ter uma resposta adequada que seja útil para outras pessoas. A impressão que seu texto dá é que as pessoas estão aqui pra prejudicar outras, que são maldosas, que levam para o lado pessoal e por isso vão prejudicar pessoas que discordam dela, geralmente isto é projeção.

Comment: Eu aprendi fazendo muitas perguntas a outras pessoas, aprendi muito com os outros, assim eu olho para os outros com olhos livres da minha exclusiva opinião, daí eu trabalho mais com fatos do que percepções, não uso soluções universais como "tudo deve ser assim" e prefiro o "deve ser assim de acordo com o contexto".

Comment: Eu costumo usar a tática dos extremos: imagine você chegar num curso de doutorado em cybersecurity e perguntar como instalar um antivírus no seu Windows 10. Sob esse aspecto, eu acho sim, que existem perguntas mal feitas e de baixa qualidade. Há outros meios de responder a sua dúvida sem ser entendiante. Não dá pra ser uma pergunta abrangente demais, isso aqui é um fórum, não um curso de formação. Esforcemo-nos mais!

Answer (score 2):

Como o tópico foi aberto como [debate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debate) vou deixar aqui a minha impressão e opinião [01:40].

O site tem hoje um pouco mais de [90 mil usuários](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/526/year/pt-stackoverflow/2018-01-01). Tudo que envolva muita gente sempre aparece conflitos, discórdias, contradições de opiniões etc. (fico imaginando como deve ser o SOen que tem dezenas de milhares de usuários).

É natural a gente desejar uma comunidade onde as coisas sejam perfeitas, mas não é bem assim, e devemos estar preparados para isso. O site é aberto a qualquer um que queira entrar. Um usuário pode até ser banido, mas ele faz outra conta e entra novamente. Isso é inevitável.

Ao ler o contexto da pergunta (longo, diga-se de passagem, mas li tudo) vi que o conteúdo passou do título da pergunta para um verdadeiro desabafo, porém bem válido, ainda mais pelo status de moderador que possui, o que é digno de consideração e atenção.

Antes de entrar no mérito do tópico, o que mais me impressiona não é nem a baixa qualidade das perguntas, é a incapacidade que as pessoas têm em se expressar e pior ainda (antes fosse apenas a incapacidade em se expressar) são os erros de português. Realmente não sabemos falar a nossa língua materna. Isso é fato: somos um povo que não sabe escrever a nossa língua.

O que mais me impressiona é o fato de que estamos falando de gente que, vou ser otimista, lidam com coisas complexas (programação) para a maioria das pessoas e escrevem um português de péssima qualidade, como se fossem analfabetos.

Voltando ao tópico da pergunta, cara, acho que você está sendo duro demais consigo mesmo. Deixa as coisas rolarem. Onde tem muita gente (ainda mais brasileiro) não podemos esperar que as coisas sejam como desejamos que fossem. Eu ando na rua e vejo gente descartando embalagem de papel de chocolate em via pública. Desde pequeno fui ensinado que isso é errado mas, porquê aquela outra pessoa joga? Como somos uma população muito grande, diversificada e capitalista, muitas vezes as pessoas não têm acesso a uma educação cidadã ou não buscam ter, e temos que conviver com isso.

Da mesma forma é o site. É apenas um site. Eu vejo muita coisa errada também.

Então, acho que tem que deixar as coisas rolarem. O que for ruim é ruim, o que for bom é bom. Ficar sonhando com uma comunidade perfeita pode levar a gente a paranoia.

Eu adoro o SOpt e vejo que muitas coisas poderiam ser melhoradas, mas acho que se deve levar ele *leve*; é apenas um site, não é seu nem meu, é de um grupo privado que pode fazer dele o que quiser. Se quiserem fechá-lo amanhã, o farão. Deixe as coisas rolarem a façamos o que for do nosso alcance. [02:44]

Comment: 01:40, 02:44? Achei isso curioso... enfim, ao que interessa: eu gosto da ideia da perfeição para ser um guia de onde ir, não necessariamente alcançar. Como uma assíntota =]

Comment: :D.. Sim, levei 1 hora para escrever essas "asneiras"... Concordo plenamente com vc: a perfeição é algo a ser buscado, mas nunca presumidamente esperada alcançar, como essa minha resposta, por exemplo.

Answer (score -3):

Mais um usuário novo aqui.

**Introdução/Contextualização:**

Se o site quer crescer, e aumentar a qualidade, deveria receber bem os novos usuários. Precisamos trabalhar com a realidade que temos, com as pessoas que temos. Não estamos no Vale do Silício, nosso país tem suas dificuldades, tem seus méritos. Os EUA também tem vários problemas, mas atrai os melhores programadores do mundo. O SO em inglês, por sua vez, agrega não apenas os melhores programadores dos EUA, mas também os melhores da Europa, Ásia, das Américas (inclusive do Brasil), da África, da Oceania. Se quiser tomar o site em inglês como parâmetro de qualidade, vai viver eternamente frustrado. E não é justo culpar os novos usuários pela sua frustração.

Os brasileiros são batalhadores que matam um leão por dia para sobreviver. A maioria da população vive com menos de meio salário mínimo por dia. Se você ganha 3 mil reais por mês, está entre os 10% de maior renda do país. Metade da população adulta não tem ensino médio. Um terço não tem ensino fundamental. Daqueles que chegam ao nível superior, metade não se forma. Dos que se formam, metade trabalha em empregos que não exigem qualquer qualificação. Num mercado de trabalho de alta-rotatividade, onde metade é informal. O Brasil é o contrário do que o complexo de vira-lata diz: aqui a regra é muito trabalho e pouca recompensa, para a maioria. Para os bem-nascidos é outra a história.

Daí um cara ou uma mina tem um subemprego, resolve fazer um curso noturno de programação ou aprender a programar por conta própria para melhorar de vida. Tem uma dificuldade com a lição de casa, porque está aprendendo, e vem postar a dúvida aqui. A pessoa faz o cadastro no site e procura redigir uma pergunta sobre um assunto que está conhecendo. Isso já é um trabalho maior do que o de pesquisar no Google. A pessoa não conhece os termos direito ainda, se conhecesse, não precisava vir perguntar aqui. Achava no Google. O que acontece?

Em meia hora, a pergunta da pessoa recebe 3 votos negativos e é fechada. Mandam ela ler um documento ditando um monte de regras para fazer uma boa pergunta e já dizendo um monte de coisas que a pessoa precisa fazer para se adequar ao site, dominar uma série de conteúdos e que se ela não dominar, então ela "não serve para programar" e será poupada de frustrações futuras pelos bondosos moderadores frustrados com os novos usuários. Se fosse eu nessa situação, nunca mais voltava nesse site.

Como já usei o SO em inglês para várias coisas e estou com mais tempo livre em casa por causa da pandemia, li todos os documentos e tentei melhorar minha pergunta. Mas as perguntas fechadas dificilmente são reabertas. Já fiz duas perguntas no site em inglês, nenhuma foi negativada. Fiz uma pergunta aqui, recebeu 4 negativos, 4 positivos e foi fechada.

Passei os últimos dias dando uma olhada nas novas perguntas. Esse é o padrão:

> eu fechou (sic) ou negativo 80/90% das perguntas que eu leio

A maioria das perguntas é negativada e fechada em minutos. Na boa, prefiro o site em inglês, que ao mesmo tempo tem nível mais alto e é menos elitista que esse aqui.

**Resposta/Diagnóstico**

Minha resposta: o problema com os novos usuários é um problema dos moderadores que não têm a menor noção da realidade brasileira, para não dizer do básico de psicologia comportamental, e adotam uma postura elitista e punitivista em relação aos novos usuários. Essa postura é que é a responsável pelo fato dos novos usuários não procurarem maior engajamento com o site e não evoluírem.

Querem formar bons usuários? Deem instruções simples e tempo para eles melhorarem suas perguntas. Motivem eles a continuar aprendendo. Não fechem nem negativem uma pergunta de um novo usuário depois de meia hora porque estão cansados. Nem mandem ele ler um documento enorme que diz apenas como ele não é uma pessoa adequada para programar e não ajuda ele em nada.

Querem selecionar as melhores perguntas? Acho que a ideia do site é que a comunidade selecione as melhores perguntas, e não os moderadores. Deixem que a comunidade selecione as melhores perguntas. Aquilo que para vocês parece uma pergunta ruim, pode ser útil para outros usuários que estão em situação parecida a do novato.

Está cansado e frustrado de moderar? Larga o osso, e passa para outra pessoa que tenha alegria em fazer o seu trabalho. Certamente alguém terá, assim como provavelmente um dia você já teve. É normal, a vida é feita de ciclos. Desapega e deixa a comunidade avançar com as pessoas que têm e que estão dispostas a entrar nela, ao invés de sair ceifando tudo que vê pela frente.

Comment: Isso, quando você fizer tudo o que está pregando pode se candidatar a moderação na próxima eleição e resolver todos os problemas que vê no site, até porque se fizer os problemas já estarão resolvidos. Nós estávamos esperando chegar alguém que fizesse isso, finalmente aconteceu. Boa sorte e bom trabalho.

Comment: "*Deem instruções simples e tempo para eles melhorarem suas perguntas*" - a gente faz isso, mas pela minha experiência, não tem sido efetivo. Quantas vezes já comentamos e tentamos ajudar e não adianta nada, a pessoa se recusa a melhorar pq acha que a pergunta está perfeita (isso quando não xinga a gente), ou edita mas não melhora nada. A maioria das vezes é assim infelizmente, e depois de um tempo cansa (sugiro que vc tente fazer isso por um tempo - comente em todas as perguntas com problemas e tente ajudar a pessoa a melhorá-la - e veja por si mesmo se é efetivo).

Comment: Lembrando que o fechamento não é punição e nem definitivo, e nem é porque "estamos cansados" ou qualquer outro motivo que seja, é - entre outros motivos - para prevenir que apareçam respostas ruins (e sabemos por experiência que perguntas ruins costumam atrair respostas ruins). Lembrando que a própria comunidade pode reabrir, independente da moderação, então se ela realmente discordasse de tudo que a moderação fecha, teríamos mais perguntas reabertas...

Comment: Quando eu passo no SOen, reparo que de fato perguntas que aqui receberiam negativos e seriam fechadas duram mais tempo lá e muitas vezes nem recebem negativos, mas é que lá tem **muita coisa**. Passei alguns dias observando uma tag específica e nesse meio tempo vi umas 3 perguntas que seriam duplicatas mas que foram respondidas como se não fossem, o que é ruim...

Comment: Acho que o escopo aqui podia ser um pouco mais aberto em algumas situações, como no SOen, mas vale ressaltar que [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/100416). Lá tem pontos negativos que não temos aqui, e o contrário também é verdade. O fato do movimento por aqui ser baixo faz com que seja possível ver o tanto de besteira que tem e então acabam recebendo mais negativos. E também perguntas muito técnicas tem menos chances de terem respostas pela falta de alguém saber responder ou avaliar para votar positivamente

Comment: Entendo que o trabalho de moderação não seja remunerado. A SE é uma empresa com ações na bolsa dos EUA. Acho que deveria remunerar os moderadores, afinal ganham dinheiro em cima do trabalho de todos aqui, especialmente dos moderadores. Acho tb que os cargos deveriam ser rotativos. Justamente para evitar vieses do poder renovar as práticas.

Comment: De todo modo, sobre algumas questões levantadas aqui nos comentários. Acho que: deveriam estipular um prazo mínimo para fechar uma pergunta, por exemplo 48 horas depois do primeiro pedido de aprimoramento. Deveriam evitar também dar uma chuva de votos negativos para os novatos, enfim. Mas essa só é minha opinião sobre como fomentar o engajamento de novos usuários. Ouve quem quiser

Comment: Não sei o quanto sabe sobre o funcionamento do site, mas já conhece a nossa [lista de privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)? Essa lista é visceralmente conectada a [reputação do usuário](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/526/year/pt-stackoverflow/2020-01-01/211843/) e um artigo escrito pelo fundador do site [A Teoria da Moderação](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) cujo o lema é *Stack Overflow é comandado por você!*.

Comment: Esse artigo mostra a força do indivíduo na comunidade, mostrando como moderar o site usando dos seus [privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) obtidos através dos pontos de reputação.

Comment: Por exemplo se está descontente porque acredita que a comunidade não dá feedback suficiente nas perguntas de usuários novatos, conquiste 50 pontos e ganhe o privilégio de [comentar em todas as partes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)  e então ao invés de mandar os seus colegas fazerem, você diretamente entrega esse feedback aos novos usuários. Não precisa dizer aos outros o que fazer para ficar como quer, faça você, dê o exemplo coletando os dados e apresentando um estudo mostrando o impacto dessa atitude na comunidade.

Comment: Ah, legal, @AugustoVasques acho ótimo se fosse assim. É que pensei que aqui o meta era um site para perguntas e respostas e discutir como a comunidade deveria agir em conjunto. Mas pelo que vi, é cheio de postagem de moderador ditando regras longuíssimas para os outros usuários, que não tem nem nem sequer pergunta... só os amiguinhos aplaudindo.

Comment: Se não gostou da publicação que o usuários fez, faça você mesmo a sua publicação criando um novo debate apresentando a sua visão sobre a comunidade mostrando as atitudes que está tomando para implementar tal visão assim como o relatório de impacto dos seus atos  É seu [privilégio de comunicação seu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) como também [moderador da comunidade](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) iniciar debates aqui no META.

Comment: O Meta é para discussões **e** também para "artigos"/textos que falem sobre o funcionamento da comunidade, sem necessariamente ser uma pergunta (como [esse](/q/486/112052), e [esse](/q/7785/112052) - só pra citar 2 exemplos). Sobre o texto que citou, é uma pena que vc veja como alguém "ditando regras e os amigos aplaudindo". Aquilo é um grande esforço para ajudar os usuários a entender o site, para que não fosse preciso comentar a mesma coisa várias vezes e em vez disso só colocar um link que tem tudo que a pessoa precisa saber.

Comment: Mas enfim, se discorda disso ou quer propor alguma mudança (como essa das 48 horas), é interessante [abrir outra pergunta](/questions/ask) (uma pra cada assunto), pois aí a comunidade pode focar na discussão específica, responder, votar, etc. Se deixar a sugestão só aqui nos comentários, menos gente vê e ela se perde...

Comment: E sobre fechamentos, é interessante ler [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7928/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7470/112052)

Comment: Só uma coisa, eu vejo algumas pessoas reclamando do @Maniero ou dos outros moderadores, mas pergunto a quem reclama você já entrou no [perfil dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero?tab=summary) e avaliou uma a uma suas contribuições para comunidade? Já entrou no perfil de cada um dos [moderadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) e avaliou as contribuições de cada um deles para a comunidade. Agora compare o perfil dessas pessoas que critica com o [seu perfil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/211843/doctor-phd). PS: As informações são publicas.

Comment: Já avaliei positivamente várias respostas do Maniero sobre assuntos que me interessavam. Pelo que vi, sem dúvida é um contribuidor de destaque no site em vários assuntos. Não entro no perfil de ninguém para dar avaliar as contribuições. Procuro por temas que me interesso, ou que me sugerem, leio as respostas e avalio. Pensei que esse era o jeito certo de proceder.

Comment: Quanto a abertura de novas perguntas, concordo, tenho esse direito e já fiz isso inclusive. Talvez um dia faça novamente. Entretanto, aqui, apenas respondi a uma pergunta sobre um tema específico. Também um direito meu. Entretanto, as pessoas que pareciam preocupadas com a baixa qualidade das perguntas dos novos usuários, aparentemente, não queriam ouvir opiniões críticas ou divergentes sobre o assunto, especialmente dos novos usuários, e refletir a respeito. Queriam apenas concordar entre si. Tudo bem, direito de vocês também. Para mim, essa é uma evidência que reforça a minha resposta.

Comment: Pare de palpitar e comesse a agir. Abandone rebusque proselitista e coloque a mão na massa. Mude o que não o satisfaz, mas não aponte o dedo quando não fez nada.

Comment: Tem o outro lado tb: muito do que o site é hoje é fruto de muita discussão entre várias pessoas, até que se chegasse a um consenso - veja as perguntas antigas aqui no Meta, é **muita** discussão (eu não concordo com tudo mas pelo menos entendo o caminho trilhado para chegar onde estamos). E a maioria dos usuários novos não quer entender nada disso, eles querem simplesmente que o site mude pra ser do jeito que eles acham que é o "certo", sem entender o histórico que veio antes e as razões de muitas coisas serem do jeito que são...

Comment: ... e esse é um dos motivos que levam muitas dessas ideias a serem rejeitadas, pois não levam em conta o contexto do site como um todo (é baseado apenas na percepção limitada de quem participa há pouco tempo e não conhece o histórico). Só pra deixar claro que não sou contra mudanças, mas acredito que deve ser nos mesmos moldes feitos até então: por discussão e consenso (e pra isso precisa abrir outra pergunta específica). E aí caímos em outro problema: a baixa participação da comunidade no meta, que faz com que nada consiga ser decidido e nem mudado...

Comment: @hkotsubo, concordo mudanças são bem vindas desde que haja um estudo e critérios. Outro dia pensei na possibilidade de criar uma *tag iniciante* para concentrar perguntas dos novatos. Fiz a pesquisa aqui no META antes de fazer a sugestão e pude constatar que essa tag já existiu e a experiência foi um desastre e está documentada.

Comment: Perfeito, parei de palpitar aqui. Quando li a pergunta pensei que tinham identificado um problema procuravam respostas. Mas, claramente, eu estava errado.

Comment: Sim, identificamos um problema e queremos respostas. Mas infelizmente a solução não é simplesmente jogar uma sugestão e esperar que todo mundo concorde (e desistir porque 2 pessoas discordaram). Como já disse, o caminho é mais longo, tem que participar do site, entender como ele funciona, ler discussões antigas do Meta pra entender como chegamos até aqui, conhecer o todo, e **abrir outra pergunta** com uma sugestão específica para atacar o problema (ou parte dele, caso seja complexo, como é o caso). Esta pergunta serve como ponto de partida, claro, mas abrir outra pergunta é essencial...

Comment: ... pois assim podemos discutir especificamente a sugestão, avaliar prós e contras, etc. Sério, eu queria muito que mais gente participasse e desse suas sugestões, só que a maioria sequer sabe da existência do Meta, e os poucos que aparecem não participam de forma adequada (só querem jogar 1 ou 2 ideias/reclamações, não explicam porque isso resolveria os problemas - geralmente é só achismos e/ou ataques gratuitos a quem discorda - e querem que tudo mude magicamente do dia pra noite). Infelizmente não é assim, mudanças exigem esforço de todos e não podemos ignorar tudo que veio antes

Comment: A sugestão de esperar X horas pra fechar perguntas, por exemplo, seria interessante ver os argumentos explicando pq isso resolveria o problema das perguntas fora do escopo, e os contra-argumentos da comunidade. Mas para isso vc precisa primeiro entender porque existem os fechamentos da forma que são hoje (nos links que mandei anteriormente), pois isso te dará mais embasamento para argumentar, evita que se baseie em premissas erradas e todos ganham com o debate. Mas tem que estar disposto a discutir e ouvir opiniões contrárias. Se vai desistir na primeira discordância, aí não tem o que fazer

Comment: O usuário novato provavelmente nunca fez uma pesquisa no [banco de dados do sistema](https://data.stackexchange.com/), não possui acesso as [fermentas de moderação(estatisticas)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) e não possui experiência de uso da ferramenta Stack Overflow. Quando os usuários mais experientes levanta uma problemática eles estão se baseando em dados e sua experiência administrativa com o site. O argumentador fundamentado em dados sempre será bem aceito mesmo que haja discordância de interpretação. Argumentação sem dados é só um desabafo.

Comment: Ai seu nick é Doctor.PHP, é psicólogo começou perguntando sobre linguagem [tag:R] eu pensei(espero que não seja achismo meu), ai está um cara que lastra cientificamente seus argumentos. No momento fiquei empolgado tanto que levantei alguns dados sobre os pacotes que gostaria de comparar e descobri que um deles foi descontinuado em 2006 e somente o `geobr` deve ser usado(essa informação está nos links que passei no outro post). Por favor não `só` seja mais um que reclama sem motivos e vive se frustrando com seus próprios achismos. Faça a diferença.

Comment: Não vou discordar inteiramente, na verdade acho que todo o resto já foi explicado, mas sinceramente preciso discordar da acusação de sermos uma comunidade "elitista". A maioria de nós, usuários veteranos e moderadores ganhamos **quase nada** participando aqui, ao contrário, doamos nosso tempo, conhecimento e paciência, ou seja, totalmente o contrário. Ressalto que no SOen as perguntas não são fechadas porque são muitas e nem sempre os moderadores conseguem acompanhar todas, eu já vi perguntas ficarem 4 anos abertas e só depois disso serem notadas e finalmente fechadas devidamente.

Comment: _Então ela "não serve para programar" e será poupada de frustrações futuras pelos bondosos moderadores frustrados com os novos usuários. Se fosse eu nessa situação, nunca mais voltava nesse site._ Com essa postura não é o site que sai prejudicado, é o mercado de trabalho. Na primeira ou segunda pergunta é normal tropeçar. A esmagadora maioria dos usuários estuda os links passados e aprende a usar a ferramenta. Se não quer aprender, ir embora é ótimo, pois não tem condição de ser programador (afinal ler documentaçao e seguir é fundamental). Sugeriria tentar algo fora da área de ciências exatas.

Comment: Normalmente nem participo dessas discussões, pois é sempre o mesmo caso, pessoa que não agregou nada e vem com discurso aqui, mas sinto que está na hora de começar a por um freio nisso. Se nossa atitude o fizer ir embora...  tivemos sucesso! Estamos aqui para isso, filtrar quem vem para agregar, e espantar quem traz ruído. Você é livre para escolher seu caminho. Traga conteúdo relevante, e nos impressione! Aí vamos poder dar o braço a torcer e realmente levar você a sério! Hoje, esse post é só uma grande gasto de tempo. Agora a peteca está com você, é bem vindo para provar que estou enganado.

Comment: PS: Desculpe o ato falho, não quis ser desrespeitos seu nick é *Doctor.PHD* eu estava programando em php no momento.

Comment: Ok pessoal, entendi melhor o lado de vocês tb. Obrigado pelo tempo investido na discussão, na justificativa de suas ações e na memória do site. Realmente, neste momento, não tenho tempo, nem condições, nem conhecimentos de programação para me dedicar como vocês aqui. Mas achei que a discussão trouxe alguns pontos interessantes. E talvez futuramente possa abrir perguntas sobre esses temas.  Valeu!