# Como debugar programas pequenos

Tags: debate, perguntas

Um dos tipos mais comuns de perguntas ruins que aparecem no Stack Overflow é:

> *Eu escrevi esse programa, mas não funciona. [20 linhas de código].*

E só.

Se você está lendo isso, provavelmente é porque alguém te passou este link em uma pergunta que você fez no Stack Overflow, um pouco antes dela ser negativada e fechada (se você está lendo isso e não se encaixa neste caso, pode deixar suas dicas para debugar programas pequenos nos comentários, ou adicionando uma resposta).

Stack Overflow é um site de perguntas e respostas para questões específicas sobre código. *"Eu escrevi um código com bugs e não consigo resolver"* não é uma pergunta, é uma história, e sequer é uma história interessante. *"Por que quando subtraio um de zero obtenho um número maior que zero, fazendo minha comparação com zero na linha 12 retornar `true` incorretamente?"* é uma pergunta específica sobre código.

Então você está pedindo que a Internet *faça o debug de um programa que você escreveu*. Provavelmente nunca te ensinaram a debugar um programa pequeno, pois vou te contar uma coisa: **este não é um jeito eficiente de resolver o seu problema**. Hoje é um bom dia para aprender a debugar sozinho, porque o Stack Overflow não é um site feito para debugar os seus programas para você.

Vou assumir que o seu programa compila mas não faz o que deveria, e além disso, você tem um caso de teste que mostra que ele está errado. Vejamos como encontrar o bug.

Primeiro, **ligue todos os avisos do compilador (*compiler warnings*)**. Não há motivo para um programa de 20 linhas produzir um *warning* que seja. *Warnings* são o compilador te dizendo *"este programa compila mas não faz o que você acha que faz."*, e **como esta é exatamente a situação na qual você se encontra**, cabe a você prestar atenção a estas mensagens.

**Leia as mensagens cuidadosamente**. Se você não entende por que um *warning* está aparecendo, esta é uma boa pergunta para o Stack Overflow pois é uma *pergunta específica sobre código*. Certifique-se de colocar a mensagem exata do *warning*, o código exato que a produz, e a versão exata do compilador que você está usando.

Se o seu programa ainda tem um bug, **arranje um pato de borracha**. Caso você não tenha um pato de borracha, arranje um aluno de Ciência da Computação, é quase a mesma coisa. Explique para o pato, usando palavras simples, porque cada linha de cada método do seu programa está obviamente certa. Em algum ponto você será incapaz de fazê-lo, seja porque você não entende o método que escreveu, ou porque ele está errado, ou ambos. Concentre seus esforços neste método; *é provável que o bug esteja ali*. Sério, debugar com um pato de borracha funciona. Como o lendário programador Raymond Chen disse certa vez, se você não consegue explicar para o pato porque está executando determinado comando, talvez seja porque você começou a programar antes de ter uma estratégia.

Se o seu programa compila e o pato não tem mais nenhuma objeção, mas ainda existe um bug, você pode **quebrar seu código em métodos menores**, com cada um contendo **uma única operação lógica**. Um erro comum entre muitos programadores, não apenas iniciantes, é criar métodos que tentam fazer muitas coisas e não as fazem da melhor maneira. Métodos menores são mais fáceis de entender, e consequentemente mais fáceis para você e o pato encontrarem os bugs.

Enquanto você estiver refatorando seu código em métodos menores, gaste um minuto para **escrever a especificação técnica de cada método**. Mesmo que seja apenas uma ou duas frases, ter uma especificação ajuda. A especificação técnica descreve o que o método faz, quais as entradas válidas, quais são as saídas esperadas, os casos de erro, etc. Muitas vezes, ao escrever a especificação, você perceberá que esqueceu de tratar algum caso particular, e esse é o bug.

Se o seu programa ainda tem um bug, verifique se as especificações contêm todas as **pré-condições e pós-condições** de cada método. Pré-condição é algo que deve ser verdadeiro antes da chamada do método, para que ele funcione. Pós-condição é algo que deve ser verdadeiro depois que o método terminou seu trabalho. Por exemplo, uma pré-condição poderia ser "este parâmetro deve ser um ponteiro não-nulo", ou "a lista deve ter pelo menos dois elementos", ou "este parâmetro deve ser um número positivo", ou qualquer outra coisa. Uma pós-condição pode ser "a lista possui exatamente um elemento a menos do que tinha no início", ou "o array está ordenado", etc. Um método que tem uma pré-condição violada indica um bug em quem está chamando este método. Um método que tem uma pós-condição violada quando todas as pré-condições estão satisfeitas indica um bug no próprio método. Geralmente, ao definir as pré-condições e pós-condições, você notará um caso que esqueceu de tratar no método.

Se o seu programa ainda tem um bug, aprenda a escrever ***assertions*** que verifiquem as pré-condições e pós-condições. Um *assertion* é como um comentário que diz se determinada condição foi violada; uma condição violada quase sempre é um bug. Em C# você pode colocar `using System.Diagnostics;` no topo do seu programa e então fazer `Debug.Assert(value != null);` por exemplo. Toda linguagem tem um mecanismo de *assertions*; encontre alguém para ensiná-lo a usar na sua linguagem. Coloque os *assertions* das pré-condições no início do método e das pós-condições antes do seu retorno (isso é mais fácil se o método só possui um único ponto de retorno). Agora quando você rodar o programa, se um *assertion* falhar você será alertado sobre o problema, e não será tão difícil debugar.

Agora **escreva casos de teste** para cada método, para verificar se o seu comportamento está correto. Teste cada parte de forma independente até você ter confiança nela. Teste vários casos simples; se o seu método ordena uma lista, tente com uma lista vazia, com apenas um elemento, com dois elementos, três elementos iguais, três elementos em ordem inversa, e algumas listas maiores. Há grande chance do seu bug aparecer em casos simples, o que o torna mais fácil de analisar.

Por fim, se o seu programa ainda tem um bug, **escreva em um papel o que exatamente você espera que cada linha do programa faça para o caso que não funciona**. Seu programa só tem 20 linhas. Você deve ser capaz de escrever *tudo* que ele faz. Agora rode o seu programa **usando um debugger**, examinando cada variável em cada passo, e a cada linha verifique se o programa faz o mesmo que está na sua lista. Se ele fizer algo que não está na sua lista, então a sua lista tem um erro, e nesse caso você não entendeu o que o programa faz, ou o programa tem um erro, e nesse caso você escreveu o código errado. Conserte o que estiver errado. Se você não sabe consertar, pelo menos agora você tem uma pergunta técnica que pode ser feita no Stack Overflow! De qualquer maneira, repita este processo até que a descrição sobre a execução do programa seja igual à execução de fato.

Enquanto você roda o código no debugger, eu te aconselho a **prestar atenção às pequenas dúvidas**. Muitos programadores têm a tendência natural de acreditar que seus programas funcionam da forma esperada, mas se você está debugando, é porque esta premissa é falsa! Em várias vezes eu estava debugando um problema e via com o canto do olho aquele pequeno aviso do Visual Studio dizendo que "o endereço de memória foi modificado", e eu sabia que o endereço de memória não tinha nada a ver com o meu problema. Mas então *por que ele foi modificado*? Não ignore estas pequenas dúvidas; estude o comportamento estranho até que você entenda porque ele está certo ou errado.

Se isso parece muito trabalho, **é porque é mesmo**. Se você não conseguir aplicar estas técnicas em um programa de 20 linhas que você mesmo escreveu, provavelmente não vai conseguir usá-las em programas de milhões de linhas escritos por outras pessoas, mas este é um problema que profissionais da nossa área precisam resolver todos os dias. Comece a praticar!

E da próxima vez que você escrever um programa, **escreva a especificação, casos de teste, pré-condições, pós-condições e *assertions* de cada método antes de escrever o código do método!** Isso diminui as chances de ter um bug, e mesmo que tenha, você terá mais chances de encontrá-lo rapidamente.

Este método não encontrará todos os bugs de todos os programas, mas é muito eficiente para o tipo de programas pequenos que programadores iniciantes recebem como exercício. Por fim, estas técnicas podem escalar para encontrar bugs em programas não triviais.

---

Esta é uma tradução de [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), escrito por [Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/about-eric-lippert/) (fiquem à vontade para melhorá-la), e faz parte de uma ideia iniciada [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7170/112052).

De maneira resumida, o propósito inicial desta pergunta era atualizar o link existente na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois originalmente ela apontava para o artigo original, em inglês (atualmente o link já se encontra atualizado). Mas você também pode colocar o link desta pergunta nos comentários de qualquer pergunta feita no [site principal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) e que se encaixe no caso descrito acima ("*meu código não funciona: [linhas de código sem contexto nem explicação]*").

Comment: Quase dava menos um, eu vou ser agora um aluno de Ciência da Computação e me senti um pato de borracha.

Comment: Este post está otimo. Cada vez mais o SO está se a tornar um serviço de debugging e correção de trabalhos em vez de um verdadeiro site de perguntas e respostas. Só é pena que não dá para dar mais enfase ainda aos trechos que estão em negrito.

Comment: Acho que merece a tag destaque né moderadores, não?

Comment: Excelente, artigo realmente é algo que tem afetado a comunidade de programação.

Answer (score 3):

Muito bom o artigo. Realmente, *não vou dizer que nunca fiz*, algumas pessoas já saem pedindo soluções ao seus bugs sem ao menos se dar o trabalho de debbugar.
Não sei se com o tempo a experiência me ajudou a enxergar esses pontos de vista ou se foi apenas vergonha na cara, rs.

Dúvidas, todo mundo tem, ainda bem que tem, senão não movia o conhecimento.... mas seguindo o artigo reforço, debuguem, analisem, documentem seus códigos.

Menos é mais, a citação

> ...quebrar seu código em métodos menores, com cada um contendo uma única
>   operação lógica.

é fenomenal e ajuda muito no entendimento e na manutenção do fonte.

Parabéns e obrigado pelo artigo!