# O SOpt não se vende como um site de boas perguntas

Tags: debate, perguntas

É uma opinião.

Penso que o SOpt deveria se vender mais, no momento da criação das perguntas, como um site que busca ter **boas** perguntas e respostas. Por exemplo com um texto semelhante a esse na tela de criar pergunta:

> Faça uma pergunta que outras pessoas com o mesmo problema possam buscar também, que seja útil para a comunidade. Se ela ajudar somente você não estará de acordo com o que queremos aqui no Stackoverflow. É possível sim fazer uma pergunta que atenda não somente você mas seja útil para a comunidade como um todo. Leia na lateral como perguntar.

Acho que o site deveria deixar claro desde o começo que é um local para **boas** perguntas e não qualquer pergunta, expressando um nível de rigor que é buscado em uma *SoftwareEngineering.SE* (que, querendo ou não, vem dando certo como comunidade que valoriza e retém especialistas).

As pessoas não sabem disso quando vêm aqui fazer perguntas. Um texto curto, conciso e claro "na cara" de quem pergunta pode ajudar.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: Isso é cultura local, de buscar "qualidade", mas com certeza não é o que a empresa por trás do SOen, SOpt, SOja, SOes quer, o q a empresa quer é numeros, então por mais que nós frequentadores e moderadores trabalhemos por um conteudo de qualidade, não é o que a SO empresa quer, não quer dizer q eles querem perguntas e respostas ruins, o q eles querem é numeros, e é óbvio que numeros atraem qualidade pior.

Comment: Eu acho que o site deveria ter várias coisas nesse sentido, gosto da opinião, mas sou bem cético quanto a isto um dia ocorrer (a não ser que alguém que priorize qualidade um dia adquira a empresa, e reorganize a administração radicalmente, levando o site de volta ao objetivo inicial)

Comment: Não sei qual o caminho, mas é certo que é bem chato ver a primeira página de novas perguntas e de cada 10, entre 7 e 8 (não é chute, fiz a experiência de ver isso por vários dias seguidos) são fechadas ou negativas. Num primeiro momento faz pensar "não estão sendo rigorosos demais?", mas ao entrar nas perguntas a qualidade é muito ruim, é um enorme trabalho para a comunidade, e em especial para os moderadores, ficar votando e fechando tudo, precisa de algo pra por na cabeça das pessoas o conceito de como funciona e reduzir o número absordo de perguntas ruins que não agregam nada

Comment: acho que um grupo de perguntas que deveriamos pensar em como tentar evitar seria o das "meu código não funciona, podem ver o que é", o classic "façam debug pra mim"... um tutorial, algo que diga a quem está perguntando "antes de perguntar já fez debug? cliquei 'aqui' para saber mais" "dicas de como fazer console.log, console.write", essas coisas bem comuns? "copie o texto do log e cole aqui no lugar de imagens", etc? são ideias, pra mim perguntas nesse contexto são muitas todos os dias, e poderia dar pra ajudar/evitar se tivesse algo assim, só uma ideia

Comment: @RicardoPontual tem uma postagem no META justamente sobre isto (depurar]), copie o link e envie em seus comentários. Já deve ajudar.

Comment: @RicardoPontual por exemplo isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454663/101 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454674/101. Tem momentos que fico na dúvida de como balizar o que é ou não problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, seria essa? https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/57220
vou guardar o link aqui

Comment: sim @Maniero esse é um bom exemplo Esse ainda tem na pergunta *"Quando eu coloco o número, aparece número normal em inteiro sem máscara."*, mas olhas esse outro, um clássico "vejam pra mim pq não funciona" e só: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454604/57220

Comment: Sim. A qualidade está acima de tudo e aqui também não deve ser diferente.