# "Não existe pergunta ruim" diz o ditado. Então porque negativam minhas perguntas?

Tags: debate

A algum tempo atrás, eu encontrei o stack overflow, uma comunidade para sanar suas dúvidas na área da programação, mas ultimamente algumas das minhas perguntas são negativadas praticamente 1 minutos após elas terem sido postadas, tudo o que eu gostaria é que quem negativa as minhas perguntas me desse uma explicação, dizendo o que está ruim nela, e, ou o que poderia ser melhorado. Quero iniciar aqui uma discussão, pois sei que não sou apenas eu que sofro com isso.

Então me digam: o que há de errado com as minhas perguntas?

A primeira pergunta: [Erro ao empacotar um projeto em electron; O arquivo simplesmente não constroi a aplicação corretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459030/erro-ao-empacotar-um-projeto-em-electron-o-arquivo-simplesmente-n%C3%A3o-constroi-a)

A segunda pergunta: [Error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'Missing “code” in request.' ao tentar usar o Oauth2 do Discord](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/470882/error-invalid-request-error-description-missing-code-in-request-ao-ten)

Obs: O negativar da pergunta pode significar que 'ela não é util', como assim?Como uma pergunta pode não ser util? Alguém explica isso!

Comment: Caro Gabriel se não existe pergunta ruim, logo não precisaria existir voto de fechamento e logo as pessoas não fariam perguntas sem detalhes técnicos ou perguntas duplicatas, mas como ocorre ambos casos, fora uma série de outros motivos, então creio que esse ditado seja mais para agradar o ego de quem pergunta em sala de aula e incentivar a faze-las, mesmo que perguntas totalmente sem noção, no entanto aqui é um site que necessita de um amparo da parte de quem pergunta, o amparo técnico, ou seja precisa explicar de forma clara e simplificada os passos até obter o "erro".

Comment: ps: não fui eu quem negativou, mas acho que o motivo da pergunta 1 é bem claro, não dá pra entender o passo a passo q vc fez, e na segunda pergunta sua só vc vai poder analisar, no electron tem o modo debug q vc pode usar o inspetor de elementos/DevTools.

Comment: Existe pergunta ruim, existe pergunta que não merece resposta, existe pergunta que ninguém entende, existe pergunta que não é pertinente no contexto colocado, existe até coisas que parecem pergunta, mas não é. O que não existe é pergunta fácil demais que não deva ser feita, mas ela deva ser bem feita, e claro, deve ser uma pergunta, dentro do que se espera em um local. Minha tendência seria fechar a primeira por ser ampla, afinal não tem um problema específico, tem um problema geral. A segunda está difícil dizer qual é a pergunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *"Não existe pergunta ruim" diz o ditado.*

Bom, é só um ditado, não tem fundamentação. Fechei ambas agora que revisei, mas com explicação do motivo do fechamento e orientação no campo de comentários de cada uma.

> *... eu encontrei o stack overflow, uma comunidade para sanar suas dúvidas na área da programação ...*

Não sei bem de onde veio esta sua definição, mas compensa uma lida aqui, que é baseado na documentação oficial:

- [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70)

> *Então me digam: o que há de errado com as minhas perguntas?*

Basicamente tem tudo nos links a seguir, que servem para estas que mencionou e para futuras perguntas:

- [Como fazer um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - Essencial, faltou nas duas.
- [Que erro cometi ao fazer minha pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/70)
- [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Esta postagem pode ajudar:

- [Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/70)

> O negativar da pergunta pode significar que 'ela não é util', como assim?

Exato, PODE significar. Mas não apenas isso. O *tooltip* é `Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; ela não é clara ou não é útil`. Pode ser qualquer uma das três coisas (ou um conjunto delas).

Sobre os negativos, tem uns links nos "relacionados" lado direito desta página aqui (à direita, ao menos na exibição desktop), e a pesquisa do Meta pode ajudar (mas o motivo real, só quem negativou é que sabe de fato).

Sobre a pergunta ser útil, ela tem que ser para o coletivo. Se servir só para o autor, e principalmente se não estiver claro onde o autor tem dificuldade, ela não deve estar neste site (mas isto está explicado nos links acima).

Lembre-se que você pode editar ambas e elaborar melhor, que automaticamente elas entram numa fila de revisão. Os fechamentos quase sempre são um convite a melhorar o post, quando a dúvida pode ser enquadrada no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic).