# Minha pergunta foi fechada, não posso obter uma resposta ali?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

É, uma resposta oficial como conhecemos no momento não pode.

Isto não quer dizer que não pode receber alguma ajuda. Esta ajuda pode ser para melhorar a pergunta e ela ser reaberta, ou uma ajuda nos comentários que te dê algum rumo ou quem sabe até uma solução.

Perguntas fechadas foram consideradas ruins pela comunidade e/ou moderador e por isso ela está impedida de receber respostas oficiais. Na forma atual a pergunta deve dificultar bastante que uma resposta seja realmente boa e sirva para vários usuários.

## O que é o Stack Overflow

Aqui cabe uma explicação que muitas pessoas não entendem: [o Stack Overflow não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/101), ele é um site de perguntas e respostas e estas duas coisas precisam brilhar.

Precisa ter uma pergunta bem concebida, como se fosse uma pergunta feita em uma prova para alguém responder, por isso ela precisa estar clara, ter todas informações, ser para um ponto específico, dentro do escopo da programação, não pode ser baseada em opiniões, precisa ter um foco e principalmente precisa ser conceitual ou com um problema real que a pessoa tenha depois de tentar algo (não pode ser um enunciado pedindo para fazer para ela ou pedindo ajuda genérica, dica, luz, ou algo do tipo).

As respostas precisam de fato atender a demanda bem feita, e ajudar não só a pessoa que perguntou mas também outras pessoas que possam ler a pergunta e a(s) resposta(s) e conseguir fazer o mesmo. A resposta deve ser objetiva mas deve dar todas informações necessárias para todos entenderem aquilo.

Por isso a pergunta bem feita é fundamental. Uma pergunta mal feita tem um potencial muito grande de gerar uma resposta ruim e não é culpa de quem responde, a não ser pelo fato da pessoa ter respondido algo ruim (eu já me arrependi várias vezes de ter respondido algo que achei que estava bom, mas a pessoa não tinha a menor noção do que estava postando ali). E por isso dizer "eu entendi a pergunta, reabre" não ajuda muito, afinal precisa todo mundo entender para uma pergunta estar aberta. Inclusive porque é frequente a pessoa dizer que entendeu e aí dá uma resposta que não serve, porque ela apenas achou que entendeu.

Essas regras existem para fazer o conteúdo ser relevante e correto para todos. Quem está fazendo isso há bastante tempo costuma acertar mais que errar. Por mais que a atitude voluntariosa de quem quer ajudar seja positiva, em geral a ajuda não será tão boa e universal. Até pode ajudar, mas daí ser uma resposta satisfatória que resolva bem a questão vai uma distância.

## Não oferecemos ajuda, oferecemos respostas

Pelo menos oficialmente não é um site ajuda. Não podemos ter respostas que apenas ajudam a pessoa que postou algo. Podemos comentar sobre, não deixa de ser uma ajuda, mas sem ser oficial, sem direito à classificação porque a pergunta já não ajuda ter uma resposta real. Votos em algo que pode ter ajudado o autor da pergunta ou que despertou algum interesse pode fazer mais mal que bem, e passar a ideia que somos um fórum.

## Fechar rápido

Infelizmente a comunidade não tem sido ativa como era no passado, então quando a pergunta não é fechada rapidamente dá margem para ter respostas em cima de uma pergunta mal feita e causar mais mal do que bem, ainda que a intenção fosse diferente e que nem todos percebem isso. Depois que uma resposta ruim é dada pouco se pode fazer. Não é tradição apagar algo ruim, e votos negativos são raros o que pode fazer com que a resposta ruim fique até positivada.

## Negativos na pergunta

Existe um motivo para não custar nada para quem dá um negativo em pergunta. Perguntas ruins precisam ter sua classificação negativa garantida de forma simples. Perguntas ruins podem ser só fechadas, só negativadas ou ambos. Em muitos casos vemos perguntas que merecem os dois. Isto ajuda porque uma pergunta fechada sem respostas e negativada tende a ser removida rapidamente.

Se a pergunta não for melhorada depois de alguns dias em geral ela não serve para qualquer pessoa. Uma ajuda pontual em comentário que pode ser um simples *link*, uma indicação de um erro de digitação, ou uma dica para a pessoa quem sabe até fazer outra pergunta melhor se não for possível editar e salvar esta tem algum valor para o AP mas não para a comunidade, para ser buscada depois e ajudar outras pessoas.

Lembrando que editar e salvar a pergunta é desejável. Apagar uma pergunta ruim vai contando negativamente e o sistema pode até bloquear a pessoa de fazer novas perguntas.

## Comprometimento

Precisamos de pessoas comprometidas com sua pergunta. Se a pessoa não ligar para ela, se ela não segue as instruções mostradas no bloco azul do motivo do fechamento, se ela não quer ou não consegue melhorar a pergunta para poder proporcionar uma boa resposta (se possível com ajuda de outras pessoas no comentário) então fica complicado aceitar uma resposta oficial ali.

Se a pessoa não quer se ajudar não vale a pena manter uma pergunta assim e ela fechada e negativada dará destino correto para isto. Se a pessoa não consegue melhorar a pergunta provavelmente ela está fazendo algo que ainda não possui capacidade e deveria fazer perguntas mais simples. Ao contrário da crença de alguns, o SOpt adora perguntas de iniciantes, mas é complicado responder pergunta de experiente feita por iniciante. Ele não tem a base sequer para perguntar, e uma resposta pode causar mais mal que bem.

## Motivos para fechar uma pergunta

Hoje um dos motivos que mais tem fechado pergunta é a pessoa só querer que falem para ela como faz algo sem ela ter tentado algo, sem ser um problema específico, sem ser um conceito, ela só quer um exemplo, um código pronto, ou então algo baseado em premissas muito abertas que não permitem dar uma resposta certeira, alguém poderia chutar algo, e o autor até gostar, afinal ele sabe nada sobre aquilo, e vai considerar qualquer coisa como boa. Não por acaso tem "resposta" que na verdade é um comentário, uma outra pergunta para tentar entender o problema e recebe positivo.

Outro motivo muito forte tem sido que a pessoa posta seu código todo e diz que está com algum problema. Mesmo que o problema seja especificado, se ela não apresenta um [exemplo **mínimo**, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), fica complicado ajudar. É um enorme problema que boa parte das pessoas que postam no site não sejam programadores de fato e estão usando um trecho de código que pegaram em algum lugar e não entendem aquilo, então ela não consegue reduzir seu problema ao mínimo, ou não sabe que precisa de outras partes para resolver aquele problema. Me desculpem essas pessoas, mas elas não podem transferir para as pessoas que estão ajudando toda responsabilidade sobre o que fazer, tendo que analisar dezenas ou centenas de linhas para muitas vezes descobrir que nem dá para resolver, a pessoa precisa entregar algo que seja uma pergunta específica, o Stack Overflow também não é um depurador humano.

## Comunidade pequena

Embora tenhamos números cada vez maiores no site a comunidade está cada vez menor. Os usuários ativos minguaram e poucas pessoas procuram manter a qualidade do site, o que complica mais ainda obter bons resultados, e oferecer ajuda adequada.

Eu entendo que algumas pessoas querem ajudar de qualquer forma, mas muitas vezes essa ajuda acaba não tendo qualidade, e por culpa da pergunta. A ajuda pode ser dada em comentário se for possível e couber. Uma ajuda maior pode ser dada para melhorar a pergunta. Algumas pessoas esquecem que podemos editar tudo para ajudar, desde que não mude o sentido do que está, não coloque palavras na boca do autor. Se quer ajudar tanto assim e quer postar uma resposta oficial então vamos deixar que a pergunta fique boa em primeiro lugar, assim ajudará muita gente.

## Conclusão

As pessoas não devem ficar bravas porque alguém fechou sua pergunta, elas devem tomar isso como uma forma de ajuda para elas melhorarem sua forma de comunicação. Isto fará esta pessoa se tornar melhor em programação e em trabalho em equipe. A energia para reclamar funcionará melhor para melhorar a pergunta.

Não quer dizer que a pessoa não deva questionar algum fechamento, mas quase sempre essas reclamações são só vontade individual de receber uma resposta a qualquer custo.

Vamos melhorar perguntas para que elas fiquem abertas!

Comment: Creio que esta pergunta meta possa ter um magic link e/ou aparecer no fechamento de uma pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho que muita coisa deveria ter algo assim, mas o mecanismo não foi feito pra isso. Na verdade talvez precise de algo que mostre de uma outra forma, porque o pessoal não lê o que é do site, parece que só leem os comentários. Ou seja, a pessoa prova que não é programador mesmo, porque programador sabe da importância de ler mensagens de alerta, de ler documentação antes de usar algo. Um dos motivos que postei isto é justamente ter algo para a pessoa *linkar* em comentário dando mais alguma informação sobre o fechamento. Eu ainda vou melhorar, e sugiro outras pessoas melhorarem isto.

Comment: "As pessoas não devem ficar bravas porque alguém fechou sua pergunta, elas devem tomar isso como uma forma de ajuda para elas melhorarem sua forma de comunicação."  Aí está algo difícil, pois se até mesmo perguntas elaboradas e trabalhadas sofrem com fechamentos, imagina quem não fez? Sendo bem honesto, eu nunca consegui aprender algo com perguntas fechadas

Comment: @riki481 é uma pena não ter aprendido, e isto é justamente o problema. Eu não vou dizer que eu nunca vi uma pergunta bem elaborada ser fechada, mas isso é bem raro. Existe muito a pessoa ter tão pouca noção do quanto a pergunta é ruim e achar que ela deveria ficar aberta assim mesmo. Ontem mesmo fechei uma pergunta que a pessoa afirmou que não tinha problema algum. A pergunta era só um enunciado do que ela queria, sem ter problema específico algum, ela só queria que as pessoas fizessem aquilo pra ela. A pessoa não lê nada, é o que eu falei aí, ela só quer uma resposta, não liga pra regras.

Comment: Eu concordo, porem vejo em muitos fechamentos a falta de "topicos" básicos, sempre que fecham falam pra ler as regras da comunidade por exemplo, mas não citam bem detalhes, por exemplo: "leia as regras da comunidade sobre erros de portugues" algo base, pois talvez a pessoa pecou em um ponto, mas não em todos, na era da velocidade é bom sermos mais específicos, até pra ajudar a pessoa a se aprofundar no que errou, claro que é uma opinião, mas talvez a pessoa leu todas as regras e ainda não sabe aonde está errando.

Comment: Acredito que ja está ali a fechar, ja que está tendo esse "trabalho" não custa passar uma "direção" um comentario por minimo que seja de 1 linha, isso é aprendizado, vivência e experiência, descobrir com os próprios erros demanda tempo e não é evolutivo, evolução é pular o erro e ja partir de outro ponto, tendo como aprendizado comentários anteriores ou comentários e dicas de gente "sábia" que já passou por aquilo e possuem outros caminhos melhores e mais rapidos para obtenção do sucesso, isso também é trabalho em equipe.

Comment: @EdsonFilho concordo que é bom ser mais específico, vamos aguardar as pessoas fazerem perguntas mais específicas. Ou você acha que as pessoas que fazem perguntas não precisam ser específicas? É sempre bom ter pessoas que estão preocupadas com isso e vão fazer esse trabalho. Algumas pessoas que estão aqui cansaram. Elas estão há 6 anos só neste site muitas vezes tendo feito muitos milhares de intervenções (eu logo chegou no 1 milhão) e precisa sempre ter outras pessoas pra colaborar e fazer a sua parte porque cada vez tem mais gente pergunta se ma menor preocupação ou noção...

Comment: ...do que está fazendo ali, dá muito trabalho e só tendo muita gente pra ajudar é que isso pode ser sustentado, Claro a outra opção é as pessoas começarem se comprometer mais com as próprias perguntas, caprichar, tentar de tudo antes, pesquisar bem, analisar se a pergunta está boa, se o problema não pode ser resolvido de outra forma, quando é fechado ela ler tudo o que foi passado para ele,a fazer o MCVE que pode ajudar entender melhor o problema ou quem sabe resolvê-lo e tantas outras coisas que pode economizar tempo dela ou de outras pessoas.

Comment: Na era da velocidade as pessoas não tem tanto tempo assim para ser babá das pessoas e cuidar de tudo para elas, a não ser quando estão sendo pagas para isto. Mas é bom saber que podemos contar com você para ajudar neste ponto. Ficar lidando repetidas vezes com os mesmos erros das pessoas não ajuda ninguém evoluir nada, isso é chato, burocrático, braçal e não é de se esperar que pessoas façam isso com gosto e de graça. Por isso é sempre melhor quem precisa da ajuda tornar sua pergunta desejável. Mas ainda bem que sempre aparece pessoas interessadas em ajudar. Pena que todos cansam rápido.

Comment: Concordo completamente, é que estou a pouco tempo ativo como participante, então estou com força total, isso me fez refletir que nem todos estão com a mesma "paciência" que eu para coisas que as vezes são óbvias para quem já está a tempo no site! de qualquer forma, estarei aqui tentando manter essa força haha