# Perguntas fechadas não deveriam ter comentários desativados?

Tags: debate, comentários

Pergunto isso tendo como base esta pergunta:

- [Mapa do Brasil por regioes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438879/mapa-do-brasil-por-regioes)

Veja que o AP pede um "norte" (ou uma orientação), e a pergunta é flagrante fora de escopo, e foi devidamente fechada. Até aí tudo bem, porém um usuário qualquer pode escrever um comentário fornecendo as informações que o autor da pergunta necessita (ou seja, fornecendo um "norte"), e a pergunta, que foi fechada, poderá ser satisfeita de forma informal (digo "informal" porque ela não foi respondida pela forma normal do site, ou seja, pelo campo de resposta, pois foi fechada).

O resultado disso é o desencorajamento do autor em reformular e adequar a pergunta para que ela possa vir a ser reaberta, já que obteve a "resposta" que queria via comentários.

A pergunta mencionada acima é só um exemplo de muitos casos semelhantes já vistos. A ideia que eu quero levantar e conhecer a opinião da comunidade é: não seria melhor que perguntas fechadas tivessem a função de receber comentários desativada? Ou, neste cenário acima (pergunta fechada recebe resposta via comentário) é válido e útil para a comunidade como repositório e fonte de informação?

Comment: Tem casos que é mero helpdesk flagrante, de usuário que só vem pra isso, que eu adoraria fechar os comments (mas o site não é meu, apesar de umas críticas que a gente lê, procura seguir a documentação). Por outro lado, perguntas que não funcionam bem no nosso modelo ainda podem receber ajuda por ali (nao tenho nada contra um visitante ocasional aprender algo mesmo que fora do escopo, tem muita dúvida legitima e boa, mas que não funciona em Q&A). Agora, a maior funcionalidade do comment nesses casos é justamente para a comunidade tentar orientar o autor a melhorar o post.

Comment: TALVEZ dependendo da razão de fechamento, pudesse bloquear os comments, mas é utopia, dadas outras prioridades não resolvidas. E é mais uma coisa que vai dar pano pra manga. Se for automático, vai ter um monte de exceção que seria bom tratar manualmente. Mas se der exceção pra tratar manualmente, mais pedrada na moderação... Resumo: em partes gosto da idéia, mas além de precisar de um estudo bom para aplicar, precisaria de uma empresa muito comprometida com qualidade do conteúdo, o que não é mais o caso da SE, que prioriza quantidade agora.

Comment: Eu achei o debate interessante, e é feito uma pergunta e não uma proposta de que as pessoas poderiam ser contra, por isso não entendi os negativos, eu nem acho um debate tão bom assim, inclusive porque no que eu postei em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7928/101 já tem quase tudo o que poderia ser dito ali. Porém a resposta do Victor trouxe luz de forma específica, mas acaba sendo útil.

Answer (score 11):

> não seria melhor que perguntas fechadas tivessem a função de receber comentários desativada?

## Não.

Os comentários são úteis por diversos motivos:

- Explicar o que há de errado na pergunta para que a mesma tenha sido fechada.
- Se a pergunta puder ser salva posteriormente, dar orientações ao OP sobre o que pode ser feito para melhorar a pergunta.
- Apontar soluções e ajudar o autor da pergunta, tais como com links ou orientações do que fazer.
- Debater motivos de fechamento e/ou de reabertura.
- Se a pergunta puder ser salva posteriormente, dar alguma resposta parcial ou dica do que poderia ser feito para ajudar o autor.
- Permitir ao autor da pergunta defendê-la contra o fechamento, principalmente se for um usuário novo (embora isso seja pouco efetivo na maioria dos casos, é muito melhor do que nada).
- Permitir ao autor da pergunta interagir com outros usuários que sobre ela tenham se manifestado de alguma forma (nem sempre isso é sadio, mas felizmente a maioria dos casos são sim).
- Indicar duplicatas, outras perguntas relacionadas, ou páginas na internet que possam ajudar o autor da pergunta e talvez outros usuários que a vejam.
- Se ninguém puder comentar na pergunta, usuários irão entupir o meta com questionamentos acerca de fechamentos que ficariam bem melhor se apenas restritos às respectivas perguntas. Esse tipo de coisa só deveria ir ao meta nos casos mais polêmicos, problemáticos, graves ou controversos.
- Explicar aos usuários mais perdidos, como é que a comunidade funciona, possivelmente com links ao meta.

É verdade que temos muitas vezes perguntas tão ruins que nada disso ajuda. Mas nesse caso, essas perguntas tem que ser deletadas, e daí pouco importa os comentários. Para as demais perguntas, os comentários ajudam bastante e deveríamos valorizá-los mais.

Comment: Em geral o problema nem é a pergunta. Infelizmente é quem fez a pergunta. Não é bonito dizer isso, mas a verdade é que a pergunta ser ruim é só consequência, e por causa disso os comentários não funcionarão. Mas a gente tenta. Eles existem para isso. Todo mundo que tiver paciência e conseguir algum resultado é algo para comemorar. è pra essas exceções que eles devem sempre star aí. E serve também para atender a necessidade de *help desk* das pessoas. Eu até acho que não deveria, mas entendo que tenha alguma serventia e nem tudo será como eu quero. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7928/101

Comment: Pra mum o mais importante é justamente que após o *help desk* a pergunta suma, porque não é o objetivo do site manter um repositório de ajuda individual. Por isso acho ruim ter respostas nessas perguntas, porque ela provavelmente receberá positivo e aceitação e ficará lá para sempre, algo que só ajuda quem perguntou, muitas vezes uma ajuda até ruim, porque a pergunta já não ajudava. Isso é algo negativo para o site, mas positivo para quem quem perguntou e quem respondeu, é o individuo se colocando acima da comunidade. Eu acho errado, pena que nem todos concordam.

Comment: Por isso fecho rápido para dar chance só para o comentário, assim se tiver negativo, chegará o destino correto para aquilo, mesmo que alguma ajuda não oficial seja dada, que eu não sou contra, ainda que eu não goste tanto. Por mim limpava muita coisa que tá por aí há anos. Tem precedente. Já teve algumas "limpezas de verão" que mandou embora muita coisa com muitos votos positivos, mas aqui daria bastante barulho pra fazer.

Comment: @Maniero Acho que ajudar usuários que fazem perguntas help desk nem é o problema, simplesmente porque de todo modo, já são poucos os que se dispõe a ajudá-los. E perguntas help desk tem que ser fechadas mesmo (embora haja um monte de motivos diferentes para fechar, generalizar isso é um erro perigosíssimo). Quanto a alguém que respondeu pergunta help desk, teve voto positivo e resposta aceita, isso é muito raro de acontecer hoje em dia. Acontecia mais no passado, mas hoje em dia é bem difícil, então nem vale a pena querer implementar algo novo pra isso, pois já temos o suficiente.

Comment: Não é não, acontece muito, acho que você não tem visto. Pode até não ser o que mais acontece, mas não é pouco, eu acho que mudou sua percepção por não ver tudo.

Comment: Não é raro, na verdade todo dia vejo, acho que talvez você não tenha entendido sobre o que o Maniero se refere como sendo Helpdesk, na verdade aumentou o numero de helpdesk e nem estou falando só de corrigir problemas em servidores, trabalhos de faculdade ou trabalhos pessoais, estou falando de corrigir gafes de problema tendo que analisar tudo, o que nem implica na programação, mas sim em uma incrivel e complexa "depuração manual" pra tentar resolver o problema da pergunta na hora de responder, isso é o tal helpdesk e tem muita gente q apoia o helpdesk sem perceber ou percebendo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O número de perguntas helpdesk realmente é assustador. O que digo que é reduzido é o número de pessoas que se propõe a ajudar quem as posta, e mais reduzido ainda quem se propõe a responder. A maioria dessas perguntas acaba sendo fechada e depois deletada automaticamente sem nunca ter recebido um único comentário sequer. Poxa, mesmo em perguntas bem elaboradas, já é difícil achar quem se disponha a responder, então imagina em perguntas que são uma droga.

Comment: @VictorStafusa algumas dessas perguntas são muito fáceis de responder, quase sempre errado. Muitas das resposta stem uma linha, é mais um tentativa do que resposta, mas não deixa de ser uma resposta. Claro que muitas não tem respostas, mas esse fim de semana que eu não fiquei o dia todo no site teve várias respondidas em pergunta que só tinha o enunciado, muito mal elaborado, o que certamente produziu uma resposta ruim, ainda que certa, por coincidência. Novamente, pode não ser a maioria, mas não é uma quantidade desprezível.

Comment: @VictorStafusa acho que o numero de helpdeskers pode até parecer menor, mas é porque aumentou o numero de perguntas, o numero de helpdeskers é quase o mesmo, ou se diminuiu tem uma "turma do Bolinha" que insisti em fazer e apoiar helpdesks, não vou citar nomes, pq nem é o local e realmente é um numero elevado de usuários, até usuário "veterano" e "bem reconhecido".