# Vamos partilhar as regras da comunidade com os novos usuários

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Muito obrigado a [@JNat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23291/jnat) pela tradução.

---

> **TL;DR:**
>
> O que acham de criar banners para as perguntas mais importantes do meta?

Quem de nós não quereria que os [novos] usuários conhecessem as regras da comunidade? Penso que a maioria de nós quereria!

Como podemos ver, há quase sempre 5-7 perguntas em destaque no meta. A maiorias delas foram perguntadas há muito tempo. Parece-me que a equipe de moderação está a usar a tag [destaque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/destaque) ativamente para partilhar com os [novos] usuários algumas perguntas importantes (muito obrigado à equipe por isso!). A ideia de partilhar as regras da comunidade é ótima! Porque não o fazemos de maneira mais eficaz? Podemos, por exemplo, criar banners para essas perguntas importantes no meta e mostrá-las em rotação no Stack Overflow em Português.

#### Do que precisamos para que isso aconteça?

Precisamos da sua ajuda! Se pensa que os usuários deveriam saber de alguma pergunta importante no meta, então:

1. Deixe uma resposta a esta pergunta com uma ligação para uma pergunta ou resposta canônica no meta que queira partilhar, e uma breve explicação de por que essa pergunta/resposta é importante.
2. Se vir que já existe uma ligação para uma pergunta ou resposta importante aqui, por favor vote nela!

Em duas semanas, seleccionaremos as 5 respostas com mais votos. Criaremos banners para elas, e mostraremo-las em rotação no site. A equipe de moderação não terá que destacá-las mais, o que abrirá espaço para novas ideias!

Terei todo o gosto em ler o que pensam e quaisquer outras ideias nos comentários desta pergunta!

Ademais:

- [Uma iniciativa semelhante no Stack Overflow em Russo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020) (Sim, a comunidade Russa tem [um video sobre as mecânicas base do site](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4191/6)! =))

**Update**

Duas semanas passaram, o que quer dizer que chegou a altura de escolhermos perguntas para as banners. Obrigado a toda a gente que postou respostas nesta pergunta. De acordo com as votações, as 5 perguntas escolhidas são:

1. [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/17539)
2. [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/17539)
3. [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/17539)
4. [Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2632/17539)
5. [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/17539)

Por favor digam-me se alguma coisa está faltando. O próximo passo na iniciativa é criar as banners, o que pode demorar algum tempo. Vou manter-vos informados =)

**Update 2**

Criamos os criativos! Se tudo estiver bem, pedirei aos meus colegas que os adicionem à rotação. Por favor, digam-me o que pensam deles!

[image: ads 1]

[image: ads 2]

[image: ads 3]

Comment: Tentei traduzir para ptBR, portanto sintam-se à vontade para corrigir qualquer coisa que soe mal :)

Comment: Parece uma excelente ideia. Eu tenho vontade de fazer um vídeo explicando o SOpt, mas nunca tive tempo pra fazer, até porque não é só o conteúdo, teria um trabalho pra fazer uma boa pós produção.

Comment: Estas perguntas serão mostradas apenas para novos usuários (os mesmos para os quais aparece o indicador "New contributor")?

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu acho que somos capazes de mostrá-los apenas a todos.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky mas os banners seriam mostrados para todos mesmo ou praticamente só para quem menos de 200 pontos? Eu acho que hoje já tem isso nos banners normais em outros sites, não?

Comment: @Maniero Eu conversei comigo colegas. Eles disseram que existe uma opção para segmentar apenas usuários não registrados. O que você acha?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky não, excluiria muitas pessoas. Vamos tentando e vendo os resultados.

Comment: @Maniero Como eu sei agora, nosso sistema não permite atingir por algum limite de reputação. Você decide o que seria melhor para a comunidade, segmentando apenas usuários não registrados ou exibindo os banners para todos.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky vamos no mais simples e padrão e reavaliamos depois se não estiver bom.

Comment: Imagino que esses banners tenham que estar na página principal. Acho muito melhor até usar o espaço daqueles banners de propaganda da comunidade com isso em vez da idéia original.

Comment: Gostei dos banners.

Comment: Sempre que possível compartilho sim as regras da comunidade com os novos usuários.

Comment: @Solkarped, de uma olhada na minha [guia de favoritos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques?tab=bookmarks) aqui do META, nessa guia tenho marcados alguns posts relacionados ao funcionamento da comunidade. Espero que os links o ajude ao partilhar conhecimento com os novos membros da comunidade.

Answer (score 10):

Acho que o link mais importante a ser mostrado é o [Guia de Sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/112052) (ou a [versão resumida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/112052)), pois o principal problema que temos atualmente é a dificuldade das pessoas entenderem como o site funciona e como fazer uma boa pergunta (não só usuários novos, mas muitos "veteranos" também têm patinado um pouco nesse quesito).

Comment: Eu concordo, mas eu ainda acho que precisa dar mais uma polida nele. Ao mesmo tempo na minha última postagem indiquei que ele não ajudou muito. Entendo em parte do motivo e acho que precisa levar uma ideia sua postada em alguma lugar pra ter algumas coisas mais específicas, que é um pouco a ideia do Manual de Como NÃO  Fazer perguntas, mas de forma resumida e com a ideia mais afirmativa. Acho que aumenta a responsabilidade de termos as melhores postagens para ajudar.

Comment: Sim. O maior problema dos usuários novatos é justamente não saber como a comunidade funciona e como não saber como bem articular um pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

A [FAQ "oficial da comunidade"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/101) seria interessante? Caso não, comente, até para entendermos melhor os critérios ou para influenciar em outras decisões.

Poríamos fazer um esforço para dar uma melhorada nela.

Answer (score 5):

O que acha de incluir o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/101?).

Seria possível usar as respostas individuais? E seria interessante usá-las?

Comment: Eu só colocaria respostas específicas se pudesse ser algo mais inteligente (como já sugeri em uma das respostas, dependendo do motivo de fechamento, mostrar uma resposta específica do manual, por exemplo). Mas como parece que não dá pra fazer assim, acho que o link pro manual é o suficiente.

Answer (score 5):

Muitos usuários inciantes tentam aplicar a dinâmica de forums no site e começam usar o campo de respostas na tentativa de dialogar com o autor da pergunta ou com o autor(autores) de outra resposta na expectativa de fomentar uma discussão sobre seu problema. Então poderíamos compartilhar [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum) para minimizar esse mal entendido.

Comment: Concordo também com esse ponto de vista.

Answer (score 5):

Pra não ficar só em instruções para os usuários sobre os erros que eles cometem.

[Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2632/101)

Answer (score 5):

Um dos problemas mais comuns no site e tem post que explica isso:

[O que é o "problema XY"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/101)

Answer (score 4):

O *banner* vai ser simplesmente aleatório? Pois eu gostaria de sugerir que seja um pouco mais "esperto". Por exemplo, se a pergunta do usuário foi fechada, poderia ser mostrado ["Minha pergunta foi fechada, não posso obter uma resposta ali?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7928/112052) (ou ["A minha pergunta foi fechada. E agora?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7470/112052)).

Nestes casos, o *banner* poderia aparecer logo depois que a pergunta foi fechada, ou só aparece se o AP já teve uma pergunta fechada recentemente (já que ninguém lê o quadro azul, então talvez o *banner* chame mais a atenção). Isso é importante porque muita gente não entende os fechamentos, e acham que é alguma "punição", ou que os critérios são arbitrários, e principalmente não sabem que é possível reabrir.

Se não for possível ter o "banner inteligente", ainda sim me parece importante mostrar esses links, pois muitos não têm esse entendimento sobre os fechamentos.

Comment: Se for mais inteligente seria melhor ainda, mas pelo histórico... Se a pessoa está só lendo respostas ter banners mais genéricos dando pequenos fatos sobre o SOpt de como pode fazer uma pergunta.

Comment: Você sugeriu uma ótima idéia, que deve ser implementada como parte da interface do usuário, não banners. Nosso sistema de banners é bem simples. Podemos mostrar banners por regiões. Estou esclarecendo se podemos atingir por reputação. Receio que não possamos fazer muito mais do que isso.

Comment: Esta é uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 4):

[O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/101)

Como sempre, eu acho que podemos melhorar o texto para ajudar mais as pessoas entenderem onde estão.

Answer (score 4):

[Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101)

Outra que eu acho que poderíamos colocar, ela ensina algumas convenções que usamos, algo que muitos não seguem, mas enfim, pode ajudar.

Estou enchendo linguiça porque o sistema converteu minha tentativa de postar isso simplificadamente :D

Answer (score 4):

Vou colocar mais algumas para quem sabe usar em um nova etapa.

Acho que esta pode ajudar muito:

[Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/101)